# Como fazer um replace into de um servidor para outro?

Tags: mysql, select

Eu tenho a tabela abaixo em 2 servidores e preciso que o servidor 1 envie toda essa informação para o servidor 2 ou seja os campos `id, username, iddns, dns, ipdnstipo e ipdns` tal e qual como está.

Tabela

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trad` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `iddns` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `dns` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ipdnstipo` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ipdns` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `trad` (`id`, `username`, `iddns`, `dns`, `ipdnstipo`, `ipdns`) VALUES
    (1, 'master', 0, 'exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
    (1, 'master', 1, 'dns1.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
    (1, 'master', 2, 'dns2.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.102'),
    (1, 'master', 3, 'dns3.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.103'),
    (1, 'master', 4, 'dns4.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
    (1, 'master', 5, 'dns5.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.102'),
    (1, 'master', 6, 'dns6.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.103'),
    (1, 'master', 7, 'dns7.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
    (1, 'master', 8, 'dns8.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.102'),
    (1, 'master', 9, 'dns9.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.103'),
    (1, 'master', 100, 'exemplo1.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
    (1, 'master', 1000, 'exemplo1.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.102'),
    (1, 'master', 10000, 'exemplo1.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.103'),
    (1, 'master', 101, 'dns1.exemplo1.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
    (1, 'master', 102, 'dns2.exemplo1.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.102'),
    (1, 'master', 103, 'dns3.exemplo1.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.103'),
    (1, 'master', 200, 'exemplo2.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
    (1, 'master', 2000, 'exemplo2.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.102'),
    (1, 'master', 20000, 'exemplo2.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.103'),
    (1, 'master', 201, 'dns1.exemplo2.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
    (1, 'master', 202, 'dns2.exemplo2.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.102'),
    (1, 'master', 203, 'dns3.exemplo2.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.103');
```

Só consegui isto com as minhas pesquisas mas não funciona.

```
<?PHP
$db_host1     = "10.0.0.101";
$db_user1     = "dns";
$db_password1 = "123456";
$db_name1     = "dns";
$db_connect1  = mysqli_connect($db_host1, $db_user1, $db_password1, $db_name1);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$db_host2     = "10.0.0.102";
$db_user2     = "dns";
$db_password2 = "123456";
$db_name2     = "dns";
$db_connect2  = mysqli_connect($db_host2, $db_user2, $db_password2, $db_name2);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query(
    $db_connect1,
    "SELECT * FROM trad"
);

$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $trad = $row;
    mysqli_query(
        $db_connect2,
        "REPLACE INTO trad"
    );
}
mysqli_close($db_connect1);
mysqli_close($db_connect2);
?>
```

Comment: esse segundo servidor tem a função de backup somente ?

Comment: Ola boa noite Não é para fazer backup porque algumas partes vão ser alteradas por outro php no segundo servidor

Comment: Acho que a melhor saida aqui seria um sistema de replicarão, o seguinte artigo possui um exemplo interessante https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql

Comment: Muito obrigado mas já conhecia o tutorial e não é bem isso que eu pretendo só quero fazer o update completo de 2 ou 3 tabelas e aumentar o campo no servidor 2 quando inserido no servidor 1 se possível

Comment: Acho que dá pra dar uma melhorada nesse título... Está muito longo e confuso, creio que o anterior estava mais claro. O enunciado é o lugar ideal para por os detalhes, e não o título.

Comment: Você liberou o IP do servidor 1 no servidor 2 como host autorizado para acessar?

Comment: Sim o campo das ligações de um servidor para outro estão a funcionar sem problemas eles são incluídos com um include_once e já está a servir outros ficheiros.

Comment: Receio que o mysql não possua um recurso estilo linked server. Talvez o caminho seja implementar na aplicação.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver um dos meus problemas que era um campo especifico de um servidor para outro como se pode ver aqui [links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497503/how-to-update-a-table-from-one-server-to-another) agora preciso da tabela toda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente voce precisa setar uma chave primaria a essa tabela senão ela será **ReadOnly** e voce não podera efetuar nenhum update nessa tabela.

No caso setei o IDDNS como PK para teste sendo ele o unico campo que seu valor e diferente em cada linha.

```
ALTER TABLE `dns`.`trad` 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`iddns`);
```

O correto seria o ID, porem ele esta 1 em todas as rows...

**Codigo funcionando e testado localmente:**

```
<?PHP
$db_host1     = "10.0.0.101";
$db_user1     = "dns";
$db_password1 = "123456";
$db_name1     = "dns";
$db_connect1  = mysqli_connect($db_host1, $db_user1, $db_password1, $db_name1);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$db_host2     = "10.0.0.102";
$db_user2     = "dns";
$db_password2 = "123456";
$db_name2     = "dns";
$db_connect2  = mysqli_connect($db_host2, $db_user2, $db_password2, $db_name2);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($db_connect1,"SELECT * FROM trad");

while ($teste = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    //echo "REPLACE INTO trad VALUES(".$teste['id'].", '".$teste['username']."', ".$teste['iddns'].", '".$teste['dns']."', '".$teste['ipdnstipo']."', '".$teste['ipdns']."') \n";
    mysqli_query($db_connect2,"REPLACE INTO trad VALUES(".$teste['id'].", '".$teste['username']."', ".$teste['iddns'].", '".$teste['dns']."', '".$teste['ipdnstipo']."', '".$teste['ipdns']."')");
}

mysqli_close($db_connect1);
mysqli_close($db_connect2);
?>
```

Tambem verifiquei que os dados do campo dns estao vindo com um ponto '.' no final... talvez isso seja algum problema... só algo que notei.
Qualquer coisa deixe um comentario.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua explicação que funcionou na perfeição, em relação ao `iddns` sim já esta como primária só não esta neste poste porque primariamente a pergunta estava feita para `update` e não para `replace` os pontos no fim dos domínios são propositados é que posteriormente irá ser lido pelo `bind` e assim já lá estão.

Answer (score 0):

Visto na [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html), pude perceber que não esta passando nenhum dado para ser "inserido", sendo assim, imagino que poderia ficar assim assim:

```
$result = mysqli_query(
    $db_connect1,
    "SELECT * FROM trad"
);

mysqli_query(
    $db_connect2,
    "REPLACE INTO trad {$result}"
);
```

mas se não der certo, tenta algo assim:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $trad = $row;
    mysqli_query(
        $db_connect2,
        "REPLACE INTO trad {$trad}"
    );
}
```

lembrando que não fiz testes, então não sei ao certo.

Comment: Não funciona @Marcelo Diniz e onde foi buscar a variável `$trad` não estou a perceber.

Comment: Eu só copiei o seu código. A váriavel `$trad` esta recebendo o valor de `$row`, só isso. O que eu tinha visto no seu é que o trad estava sendo passado como string e não como váriavel, dai só fiz essa alteração, mas não teria como eu testar localmente. Explique o que esta acontecendo ao certo, qual o erro que esta dando.

Comment: Ok no meio disto todo nem me apercebi que `$trad` estava já estava a ser tratado como string mas não funciona e ao executar na shell não dá qualquer erro.

Comment: Da uma olhada que fiz alteração na resposta

Comment: Não consigo tenho me baseado também neste manual [link] (http://www.xoops.net.br/docs/mysql/manual/ch06s04.php) e não chego lá.