# Como converter uma ligação de MySQL para MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Decidi dar ouvidos a alguns utilizadores para fazer a conversão mas preciso da vossa ajuda pois tenho feito muitas pesquisas e nada funciona.

O primeiro ficheiro é:

```
<?php 
include_once("/pasta/connectserver.php");
$table = "rjpsync_tag, rjpsync_ipserver";
function assoc_query_2D($sql, $id_name = false){
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $arr = array();
  $row = array();
  if($result){
    if($id_name == false){
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $arr[] = $row;
    }else{
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $arr[$id] = $row;
      }
    }
  }else
      return 0;

  return $arr;
}
function query_whole_table($table, $value = 'ipserver1, ipsserver, ipserverfim'){
    $sql = "SELECT $value FROM $table WHERE idserver = 1";
  return assoc_query_2D($sql);
}
$export_str = "";
$result = query_whole_table($table);
foreach($result as $record){
  $export_str .= implode("",$record);
}
file_put_contents("/pasta/ipserver1.php", $export_str);
?>
```

E o segundo ficheiro é:

```
<?php
include_once("/pasta/connectserver.php");
function salvaip() {
$ip = file_get_contents('/pasta/myip.txt','r');
$ip = mysql_escape_string($ip);
$sql = "UPDATE rjpsync_ipserver SET ipsserver='".$ip."' WHERE idserver=1";
if (mysql_query($sql)) {
return true;
}
fclose($ip);
}
salvaip();
?>
```

Estes dois ficheiros estão ligados a:

```
# /pasta/connectserver.php
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/config.php");
$db_host1     = "$s_ipserver1:$db_porta1";
$db_link1     = mysql_connect($db_host1, $db_user1, $db_password1) or die (mysql_error ());
$db_connect1  = mysql_select_db($db_name1, $db_link1);
?>
```

E gostava que passa-se a estar ligado no seguinte:

```
# /pasta/connectserveri.php
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/config.php");
$db_host1     = "$s_ipserver1";
$db_connect1  = mysqli_connect($db_host1, $db_user1, $db_password1, $db_name1, $db_porta1) or die (mysqli_error ());
?>
```

Comment: Qual erro aconteceu?

Comment: Coloque o `i` na frente de **todos** `mysql`... simples assim.

Comment: @perdeu não aconteceu erro nenhum só gostava de poder ter os ficheiros ligados através de mysqli

Comment: https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php em 10 minutos vc resolve

Comment: @gmsantos já experimentei e não deu foi logo a primeira coisa que tentei mesmo antes de começar a pesquisar.

Comment: Alterou de todos? Certeza? Como você alterou? Deu um replace all em **todos** os arquivos do seu projeto?

Comment: Obrigado @Manuel Gerardo Pereira mas estou principalmente nessa pagina já há 3 semanas e não consigo.

Comment: @gmsantos Sim depois de ter conseguido a ligação com as variáveis passei de 110 ficheiros e (eu tinha dito que eram 80 mas eram 110) para somente 40 e agora só não consigo converter estes dois ficheiros.

Comment: Você vai ter bastante trabalho para fazer essa alteração.
Recomento que você use PDO no lugar de MySQLi. [PDO ou MySQLi: Qual Você Deveria Usar?](http://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059) 
 [Tutorial da construção de uma classe mais completa.](http://www.devmedia.com.br/usando-pdo-php-data-objects-para-aumentar-a-produtividade/28446)
 PDO tem suporte a vários bancos de dados e possui realmente parâmetros nomeados. Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por vezes uma orientação vale ouro resolvi um problema em horas que estou para resolver faz algumas semanas, mais uma vez obrigado.

Aqui fica os ficheiros alterados para funcionar com MYSQLI.

```
<?php 
include_once("/pasta/connectserver1i.php");
$table = "rjpsync_tag, rjpsync_ipserver";
function assoc_query_2D($sql, $id_name = false){
global $db_connect1;
  $result = mysqli_query($db_connect1, $sql);
  $arr = array();
  $row = array();
  if($result){
    if($id_name == false){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        $arr[] = $row;
    }else{
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $arr[$id] = $row;
      }
    }
  }else
      return 0;

  return $arr;
}
function query_whole_table($table, $value = 'ipserver1, ipsserver, ipserverfim'){
    $sql = "SELECT $value FROM $table WHERE idserver = 1";
  return assoc_query_2D($sql);
}
$export_str = "";
$result = query_whole_table($table);
foreach($result as $record){
  $export_str .= implode("",$record);
}
file_put_contents("/pasta/ipserver1.php", $export_str);
?>
```

E o segundo.

```
<?php
include_once("/pasta/connectserver1i.php");
function salvaip() {
global $db_connect1;
$ip = file_get_contents('/pasta/myip.txt','r');
$ip = mysqli_escape_string($db_connect1, $ip);
$sql = "UPDATE rjpsync_ipserver SET ipsserver='".$ip."' WHERE idserver=1";
if (mysqli_query($db_connect1, $sql)) {
return true;
}
fclose($ip);
}
salvaip();
?>
```

Comment: Quase perfeita sua própria solução. Mas recomendo que você use os placeholders do `mysqli` para evitar SQL Injection. Boa sorte.

Answer (score 7):

Para migrar um código que utiliza as funções mysql_* para o mysqli algumas mudanças são necessarias como adição de novos parâmetros ou a troca de ordem deles nas chamadas das funções e também utilizar os recursos disponiveis como prepared statements e controle de transação.

listar_legado.php

```
$link = mysql_connect('host', 'usuario', 'senha');
mysql_select_db('banco');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tabela';
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $item['campo1'] .'-'. $item['campo2'] .'<br>';
}
```

listar_novo.php

```
$link = mysqli_connect('host', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');
//mysqli_select_db($link, 'test'); //Alternativa para selecionar/trocar o banco...
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tabela';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $item['campo1'] .' - '. $item['campo2'] .'<br>';
}
```

Alternativa de listagem:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $item){
   echo $item['campo1'] .' - '. $item['campo2'] .'<br>';
}
```

[mysqli_connect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) permite passar/selecionar o nome da base como quarto parâmetro também é possivel fazer isso com a função [mysqli_select_db()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) seu uso é adequado quando é preciso trocar a base de dados(caso esteja no mesmo servidor) pois é comum um sistema acessar vários bancos.

mysqli_fetch_* retorna apenas um registro enquanto [mysqli_fetch_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) retorna um array contendo todos os registros de uma só vez, o segundo parâmetro indica a forma que os dados seram acessados(`MYSQLI_NUM` array numerico, `MYSQLI_ASSOC` associativo e MYSQLI_BOTH array associativo e numerico. Não existe uma opção para um array de objetos.) posteriormente caso ele seja omitido o padrão será `MYSQLI_NUM`.

---

**Insert, update, delete, consultas dinâmicas e prepared statements**

Prepared statements evitam sql injection dessa forma não é necessario utilizar [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) para cada valor do tipo string e dê fim a aquele mar de aspas simples/duplas.

insert_legado.php

```
//conexão omitida

$nome = 'nome\'s ); drop table ....';
$id = 1;
$nome = mysql_real_escape_string($nome);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (id, nome) VALUES($id, '$nome')";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

insert_novo.php

```
//conexão omitida

$sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela (id, nome) VALUES(?,?)';

$stmt =  mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
$id = 1;
$nome = 'nome\'s ); drop table .... ';
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'is', $id, $nome);

if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    echo mysqli_error($link);
}
```

[mysqli_prepare()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) cria uma consulta preparada baseado na string passada(`$sql`), após isso é feita a 'substituição' dos placeholders `?` pelos respectivos valores em [mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, tipo, $vars)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) onde `$stmt` é a consulta preparada, tipo são os tipos de cada valor `i` => inteiros, `s` => campos texto/varchar etc... `d` => float/double e `b` => blob e `$vars` são as variáveis(`$id, $nome...`) caso nenhum erro acontece a instrução é executada através de [mysqli_stmt_execute()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php).

**Relacionadas:**

[Select com prepared statements MySQLi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93028/91)

[Mysqli fazer bind com um array de valores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101977/91)

Comment: Interessante este seu ponto de vista seria possível aplica-lo a um select num servidor e replace into em outro servidor? [Ver aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31667/como-fazer-um-update-de-uma-tabela-completa-de-um-servidor-para-outro-e-quando-i)

Comment: @RjpServidor, dessa forma acho que não, você viu o federated engine? se não me engano tem umas perguntas aqui sobre ele talvez te ajude.

Comment: Sim vi mas não e isso que eu pretendo

Answer (score 4):

O problema que vocês está enfrentando é provavelmente com a função `mysql_query`.

Ela teve uma alteração na assinatura do método e é preciso passar o `link` do DB como primeiro parâmetro ([documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php)):

```
mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query )
```

Ou seja, para todas ocorrências de `mysql_query($var)`, substitua por `mysql_query($db_connect1 , $var)`

Usando uma IDE, é bem simples essa alteração em todos os seus arquivos a partir do replace de uma expressão regular:

Pattern da busca

```
mysql_query\(($var)\)
```

Substituir por

```
mysqli_query\(\$db_connect1, $1\)
```

Exemplo no [regexr](http://regexr.com/39h1e).

Comment: Ok @gmsantos até aqui estou a perceber e como é que fica nos casos `($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` e `mysql_escape_string($ip)` não estou a encontrar nada compatível.

Comment: Na maioria das funções, basta adicionar o `i` : http://br1.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php - http://br1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php

Comment: Sim sim já cheguei a essa conclusão um deles já esta a funcionar estava a esquecer-me de colocar `global` dentro da função.

Comment: Confira a documentação do [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli.php) caso tenha dúvidas.