# Qual é o modo certo de se conectar com o banco de dados MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

tenho uma dúvida que tem me trazido diversas incompatibilidades. Com a evolução do PHP e Mysql, surgiram versões mais recentes, desta forma o Mysqli. Eis ai que reside meu problema, gostaria de saber qual é meio correto de conectar.

Com o Mysql era:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
```

E com o Mysqli ?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","nome-tabela");
```

ou

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
```

Quando, olho no manual PHP, está uma abordagem mais orientada a objetos, mas nunca tinha visto deste modo.

Comment: Ambas funcionam bem. Vai do seu estilo de uso. Eu particularmente gosto do modelo funcional, mas é apenas uma questão de gosto e contexto, a funcionalidade é idêntica. E o bom é que a mysqli é muito parecida com a mysql, então a migração de uma pra outra é bem simples (até por ser especializada em MySQL, qualquer alternativa é inferior)

Comment: Já considerou usar o PDO? mysql_ são funções depreciadas do PHP.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Não existe uma maneira certa, tanto o estilo orientado a objetos e o procedural servem para um determinado caso.

Em projetos novos de preferencia ao estilo OO é mais prático por que não é necessario passar a variável de conexão para outros métodos como o [query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), [fetch_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) etc.

```
<?php
//Estilo orientado a objetos
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user","password","database");
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tabela");
$itens = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

No caso de um sistema já escrito a [migração das funções mysql_*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32820/91) deve ser troca pelo estilo procedural do mysqli pois acarreta menos impacto na mudança o que muda é ordem dos parâmetros e a obrigatóriedade de passar a conexão nas funções.

```
<?php
//Estilo procedural
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'database');
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM tabela');
$itens = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Eu uso dessa forma.

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser testar a conexão e exibir uma mensagem com botão Ok

```php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbname");

if(!$con){
  die("Falha na conexao: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
  echo "
  <script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Conexao realizada com sucesso.");
  </script>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando o mysqli OO em um singleton. Retorna a conexão que só é criada se for utilizada. Evita ficar passando variável por todo o código. Evita muito código.

```
function db(): mysqli
{
    static $db;
    $db OR $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'database');
    return $db;
}

echo db()->query('SELECT 1+1 AS `soma`')->fetch_object()->soma;
```