# Pegar campo na tabela com Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou tentando criar  em meu código uma comparação para verificar se a senha digitada é igual a cadastrada.

Usei da seguinte forma;

```
function confirmaPedido ($conexao, $numeroPedido, $senha) {
$querySenha = mysqli_query($conexao, "Select senha from adm where senha = $senha");
    if (!is_numeric($numeroPedido) || empty($numeroPedido)) {
        echo "Por favor insira um NUMERO no campo numero do pedido";
    }
    elseif ($senha === $querySenha) {
        $queryApaga = mysqli_query($conexao, "delete from pedido where pedido = $numeroPedido");
        echo "Pedido finalizado com sucesso.";
    }
    else {
        echo "Senha ou Pedido não são validos, tente novamente!";
    }
}
```

Se eu usar o operador para verificar se `$senhaPedido` é exatamente igual a `$senha` o código pula para o Else.
eu recebi a resposta de um outro usuario porém não consegui entender muito bem.

> mysqli_query retorna um mysqli_result. Você vai ter que usar mysqli_fetch_* para pegar a linha e daí sim pegar o campo "senha".

Como assim query retorna result? qual a diferença entre os 2? e como faço para "selecionar" o campo senha na tabela e verificar se é idêntico?

Answer (score 2):

Arrumando só o que você pediu, seria algo assim:

```
function confirmaPedido ( $conexao, $numeroPedido, $senha ) {
   $resultado = mysqli_query( $conexao,
      "SELECT senha FROM adm WHERE senha = '$senha' "
   );

   if (!is_numeric($numeroPedido) || empty($numeroPedido)) {
      echo "Por favor insira um NUMERO no campo numero do pedido";
   }
   elseif( $result->fetch_row( $resultado ) ) {
      $queryApaga = mysqli_query($conexao, "delete from pedido where pedido = $numeroPedido");
      echo "Pedido finalizado com sucesso.";
   }
   else {
      echo "Senha ou Pedido não são validos, tente novamente!";
   }
}
```

O `$result->fetch_row( $resultado )` serve para pegar a saída da *query*. Neste caso, não estou usando o resultado propriamente dito, pois se o `where` retornou algo, é por que a senha já bateu.

Agora, segue uma lista de coisas que você pode levar em consideração para fazer uma aplicação mais completa:

- Você está armazenando as senhas na base de dados. Isto é péssimo em termos de segurança, o ideal seria armazenar de maneira irreversível (usando algum tipo de **[hash + salt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/70)**, no mínimo), e ao testar a senha fornecida pelo usuário, repetir o processo e ver se ps *hashes* batem.
- Você está concatenando *strings* para fazer seu SELECT. O ideal é usar *binding* para evitar injeções SQL e também organizar seu código. **[Aqui tem mais detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47437/70)**
- Você primeiro está pegando os dados do DB, e testando o número do pedido depois. Muito melhor é testar o número do pedido, pois se ele vier vazio você não precisa nem fazer a *query*, que será em vão nesta situação.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Bacco, você poderia me dizer como funcionaria no Procedural style?

Ainda sou iniciante quando se trata de banco de dados com PHP, estou bem no começo ainda e estou tentando me virar usando a "minha lógica" entende? quero ver se da forma que eu penso funciona.
logo irei me aprofundar em questão de segurança e tudo mais.

Comment: o procedural é o que eu usei dentro do elseif, `$objeto->método()` em vez de `mysqli_fetch_row()` eu usei o $retorno, que é um objeto "result", e deste objeto eu chamei o método `fetch_row`.

Comment: RafaelAcioly veja sobre o procedural vs funcional nesta resposta do @rray: **http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33625/70**