# Relatar erro ao realizar UPDATE com SQL

Tags: php, mysql, table

Tenho um projeto, no qual o administrador poderá mudar dados cadastrados de tabelas, mas caso a consulta seja executada, mas não ocorra nenhuma mudança, gostaria que retornasse uma mensagem ou erro, eis o que tenho até agora:

```
$altera = "UPDATE z SET y= a WHERE x= x";
$select = mysql_query($altera);
if($select){
   mensagem de sucesso
}else{
   mensagem de erro
}
```

As váriaveis e coisas do tipo não são importantes, o que importa é o `if` ali no final, que, penso eu, que se a variável ocorrer, fará o que há dentro do colchetes, se não ocorrer, mostrará mensagem de erro, mas isto não funciona, e não sei mais para quem recorrer.

Comment: O que está propriamente a correr mal ? Aqui parece estar tudo em ordem.

Comment: Como disse logo abaixo @Edilson, contanto que eu digite campos verdadeiros, retorna mensagem de sucesso, apesar de não existir tal valor.

Comment: @Edilson, com relação à sua resposta, ao pegar a variavel $select e utilizá-la deste modo, ela fica como sendo boolean, porém, o mysql_affected_rows funciona como integer, e a $altera, vem como string, por um acaso teria como resolver este problema?

Comment: Foi erro meu na escrita da sintaxe. Vou agora editar a resposta.

Comment: Pronto, agora já deve funcionar. O indentificador passado a essa função deve ser o link de conexão `mysql_connect`. Se não for especificado, `mysql_affected_rows` usa automaticamente o última conexão a ser aberta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito utilizando a função `mysql_affected_rows` que retorna o número de linhas realmente afetadas na última consulta usando o `UPDATE`.

```
$altera = "UPDATE z SET y= a WHERE x= x";
$select = mysql_query($altera);
   if($select){
      if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
        print "foram atualizadas (". mysql_affected_rows() .") linhas";
      } else {
        print "consulta efetuada, mas nenhuma linha modificada";
      }
   }else{ 
      die("Erro: " . mysql_error());
   }
```

Indiferentemente do que se deseja, tanto o `if($select)` ou `if(!$select)` como um `mysql_errno()` teriam o mesmo impacto se fosse para verificar se essa consulta foi executada, sendo que o `if($select)` verifica se o valor retornado foi executado *(**true**)* ou  não *(**false**)*, `mysql_errno()` retorna o número de erro da última operação, caso esta tenha falhado, do mesmo jeito que faz o `mysql_error()` porém esta retorna o erro como valor numérico.

Para o problema de compatibilidade com versões ainda mais inferiores, existe a função `mysql_numrows()` *(também descontinuado)*.

> **Warning** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension
>   should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ
>   for more information.

Na documentação em português esse aviso é omitido, o porquê não sei, mas ele praticamente diz que funções do tipo `mysql_*` estão [obsoletos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation), ou seja, é desencorajado o uso destas funções, à partir do `PHP >= 5.5.0` e foram completamente removidas à partir do `PHP >= 7.0.0`.

Como alternativa, existem as seguintes extensões:

- [MySQLi (MySQL Improved)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
- [PDO (PHP Data Objects)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

## Algumas referências:

- [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)
- [Qual é o modo certo de se conectar com o banco de dados MySQLi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33622/qual-%C3%A9-o-modo-certo-de-se-conectar-com-o-banco-de-dados-mysqli)
- [MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8302/mysqli-vs-pdo-qual-o-mais-recomendado-para-usar)
- [mysql_errno](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php)
- [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)
- [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 4):

**Utilizo dessa forma com o Firebird:**

```
if ($query){
    echo "Tudo OK";
}

if (ibase_errmsg()){
    echo "Erro técnico: ".ibase_errmsg();
}
```

Você pode fazer com a função `mysql_error()`.

> mysql_error — Retorna o texto da mensagem de erro da operação MySQL anterior

**Exemplo com MySQL com o seu problema:**

```
  $altera = "UPDATE z SET y= a WHERE x= x";
  $select = mysql_query($altera);

  if($select){
      // tratativa caso for bem-sucedido
  } 

  if (mysql_error()){
      // tratativa caso for mal-sucedido
  }
```

**Observação:**

As funções do MySQL que iniciam com `mysql_*` estão obsoletas e serão descontinuadas a partir do PHP 7, considere utilizar `mysqli_*`.

**Referências:**

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-error.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ibase-errmsg.php

Comment: sugeriria usar apenas if + else com mysql_errno() para verificação, em vez do if($select) e mais um if redundante. O mysql_error() fica melhor para mostrar a mensagem na tela opcionalmente.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão @Bacco, vou lembrar a próxima vez que precisar tratar uma exception no php