# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de utilizar mysqli orientado a objetos?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, mysqli

Sempre utilizei o `mysqli` da maneira que eu achava mais prática e nunca percebi quaisquer diferenças. Então me veio a pergunta: por que utilizar o `mysqli` orientado a objetos? Quais suas vantagens e desvantagens?

Para deixar o entendimento mais fácil, um exemplo do que estou dizendo:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'usuario', 'senha', 'meusite');
$mysqli_query($mysqli, $comando);
```

E como ficaria orientado a objetos:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'usuario', 'senha', 'meusite');
$mysqli->query($comando);
```

Diferente [dessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33622/qual-%C3%A9-o-modo-certo-de-se-conectar-com-o-banco-de-dados-mysqli) pergunta, eu não gostaria só de saber qual a melhor maneira. E sim saber detalhadamente o que difere entre os 2 métodos.

Comment: Zero, as duas são a mesma coisa. A diferença é que um é estilo procedural e a outra é OO. https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php

Comment: relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33622/qual-%C3%A9-o-modo-certo-de-se-conectar-com-o-banco-de-dados-mysqli

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55493/quais-as-vantagens-pr%C3%A1ticas-de-se-utilizar-orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos-no-dia-a-dia-de?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O consumo de API OO ou procedural muda muito pouco. A vantagem costuma se dar no desenvolvimento, o que no caso do PHP não ajuda muito porque a versão OO é só uma casca em cima do procedural. E as pessoas confundem muito em criar algo OO e consumir OO.

Pra não falar que não há vantagem alguma, tem uma se o IDE souber o que fazer. Ele pode sugerir os membros que pode usar em objeto daquele tipo já que o objeto é o foco. Mas o IDE teria que fazer uma análise complexa ou fazer um chute porque a linguagem possui tipagem dinâmica e pode ter *scripts* injetados, ou seja, IDE não faz isso porque pode dar muito errado, então a vantagem é quase teórica.

Qualquer coisa que seja usada sem uma boa justificativa, que traga alguma vantagem, eu acho ruim usar.

Fora que é comum as pessoas não usarem OOP em PHP de maneira correta, o que piora a situação. Na verdade isto corre em outras linguagens também, mas em PHP é terrível. Daí mesmo vantagens que poderiam advir do uso de OO acaba se evaporando.

Até existe desvantagem já que é uma camada a mais pra executar, mas não é algo relevante em PHP.