# Diretrizes para uso de orientação a objetos ou procedural no Python e PHP

Tags: php, python, orientação-a-objetos, procedural

Estou estudando PHP e Python e estou sentindo uma enorme dificuldade, não em relação a conceitos, afinal os mesmos independem de linguagem, o que está tornando árduo o estudo é a forma como PHP implementa a manipulação de seus objetos, segue um exemplo:

```
// Em PHP
>>> $frase = "Lorem ipsum";
>>> echo str_replace(" ", "<br/>", $frase); // "lorem<br/>ipsum"  

# Em Python

>>> frase = "Lorem ipsum ...";
>>> print(frase.replace(" ", <br/>))
```

Sempre que se inicia seus estudos em POO a informação que mais se repete é:

> Em orientação a objetos, uma classe é uma descrição que abstrai um
>   conjunto de objetos com características similares. Mais formalmente, é
>   um conceito que encapsula abstrações de dados e procedimentos que
>   descrevem o conteúdo e o comportamento de entidades do mundo real,
>   representadas por objetos. De outra forma, uma classe pode ser
>   definida como uma descrição das propriedades ou estados possíveis de
>   um conjunto de objetos, bem como os comportamentos ou ações aplicáveis
>   a estes mesmos objetos.

Então porque ao tentar acessar dados em, por exemplo arquivos, *arrays* e outros, ou até mesmo modificar seu estado devo utilizar de funções e não métodos que ao meu ver faria todo sentido serem definidos numa classe e utilizados como método.

Quero ressaltar aqui que o que estou dizendo pode estar errado (afinal se estivesse certo não estaria perguntando), gostaria que sanassem minhas dúvidas do porque a implementação das duas é tão diferente.

Comment: Bem vindo ao mundo da programação! Inconsistências como essas são comuns, principalmente no PHP que é uma das linguagens mais inconsistentes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que não contam nesses cursos e tutoriais é que OOP é completamente desnecessário em qualquer situação. É útil em alguns casos porque organiza melhor e atende certas linhas de pensamento. Raros os problemas onde orientação a objeto é fundamental. Em GUI, por exemplo, é bastante. Em domínios de negócios é raro ser necessário de fato. [Em linguagens de *script*, especialmente as que executam e terminam partes OOP é um completo exagero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108227/101). Mas conseguiram deturpar isso.

[Existem diversas definições do que é OOP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101), o que já mostra como é algo complicado de trabalhar. Alguns dizem que OO sequer é paradigma.

Há controvérsias sobre essas coisas, e dizer que faz todo o sentido exige que você explique porque o faz. Usar algo exige uma justificativa sempre. Não usar não precisa, apenas poderia ter uma. Nunca use algo sem saber porque está usando.

[Qual o ganho que espera ter no segundo código em relação a fazer o primeiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215799/101) Eu vejo um, e somente um (ou dois), mas não vou dizer :P

E quem disse que a forma que escreveu no Python é realmente orientada a objeto? Tem gente que diz que é. Tem gente que diz que apenas é uma notação orientada a objeto, mas nada garante que seja OOP. De fato pode ser só uma construção de linguagem.

Eu até gosto da notação orientada a objeto, o paradigma um pouco menos.

E se for, qual a vantagem que teve? Será que precisava disso mesmo? E se fizer errado, será que é tão útil quanto parece? Será que não tem um meio termo?

Não tenho nada contra certas coisas serem colocadas em classes. Por algumas definições (a minha) isso não é orientado a objeto, só envolve encapsulamento, ou nem isso, só envolve uma certa abstração. Para tipos pode ser uma boa, para mecanismos tem vantagem, mas na forma como as pessoas costumam usar nem sempre.

Veja: [PHP mistura códigos de orientação a objetos e linguagem procedural?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101).

PHP começou com um objetivo, depois mudou e ficou uma bagunça, porque nem é uma coisa e nem é completamente a outra. É o marketing se sobrepondo à engenharia.

O que me preocupa mais é que a maioria das pessoas "usam" OOP sem entendê-lo e eu fiz isso por décadas, até que percebi melhor o que era OOP e comecei usar melhor, e menos porque usei onde era adequado. E parei de chamar de OOP o que sequer era. O Stack Overflow (EN e PT) foi importante pra eu me tornar mais questionador e ter onde ver a experiência de outras pessoas, de colocar meu conhecimento à prova com pessoas que conhecem certas coisas melhor que eu.

Por isso sempre falo que o fundamento é mais importante.

Answer (score 2):

O entendimento da sua questão é o seguinte: Você pode desenvolver uma aplicação em PHP com código procedural e/ou orientado a objetos.

O trecho de código que você citou do PHP **não é orientado a objetos**. É uma **função** que pega o valor da variável `$frase` e faz a substituição.

No Python, ao contrário, você está chamando um método da classe `str` para realizar o mesmo procedimento, OOP.

Encontrei esse artigo que possui uma boa explicação da diferença: https://bar8.com.br/abap-oo-versus-procedural-50474ff371a5