# Fazer um consulta SQL com o codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Gostaria de puxar algumas informações da minha database chamada "**site**", dentro dela iria conectar com a tabela: "**posts**" e nela queria mostrar a informações como: "**id, updated, title, description, link, image**" com limite de 3 e encaixar no meu código. Estou usando o codeigniter.

```
<div class="blog-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-30" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <article class="post-wrapper">

        <div class="thumb-wrapper">
            <a href="blog-single-fullwidth.html"><img src="link da imagem.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
        </div><!-- .post-thumb -->

        <div class="blog-content">
            <div class="case-studis-border"></div>
            <header class="entry-header-wrapper">
                <div class="entry-header">
                    <div class="entry-meta">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li>
                                <a href="Link">DATA</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="link">Título</a></h2>

                </div><!-- /.entry-header -->
            </header><!-- /.entry-header-wrapper -->

            <div class="entry-content">
                <p>Descrição</p>
                <a href="link">ler mais</a>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

        </div><!-- /.blog-content -->

    </article>
</div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
```

Comment: Você fez a conexão com o mysql? ou é nisso que tem dúvida?

Comment: É nisso que tenho dúvida

Comment: [Qual é o modo certo de se conectar com o banco de dados MySQLi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33622/91) e [Usar PDO é a maneira mais segura de se conectar a um BD com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91)

Comment: Você precisa fazer uma Classe de Conexão;
Uma Classe de Persistência exemplo: "UsuariosDao" nessa classe que vai rodar a query "SELECT * FROM USUARIO" isso vai depender de qual framework você está utilizando, Codeigniter, Symfone, PDO e etc.
Depois você vai ter que passar os dados para a View.
Primeiramente de tudo, qual solução PHP você está trabalhando?
@EvertonGouveia

Comment: Estou usando o codeigniter, mas sou muito aprendiz no php, com muita ajuda, estou tendo outros problemas com url também

Comment: Mas queria puxar de forma simples mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro passo é configurar o arquivo [application/config/database.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/database.php) com as informações do banco de dados como driver, usuário, senha, nome do banco e outras opções

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'USUARIO',
    'password' => 'SENHA',
    'database' => 'MINHA_BASE',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

No controller lembre de carregar a biblioteca database (ou se já deixa ela carregada por padrão em todos os controlles via [application/config/autoload.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/autoload.php), o código para consulta é o seguinte:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT id, updated, title, description, link, image FROM posts');

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
        echo $row->id;
        echo $row->title;
        echo $row->description;
}

echo 'Total Results: ' . $query->num_rows();
```

- `result()` retorna um array de objetos.
- `row()` retorna apenas uma linha ou proprio objeto.

Comment: não estou conseguindo, estou uma usando uma página customizada do codeigniter "custom.php", eu tenho uma página chamada "posts_list.php" teria como dá um "Include" no "custom.php"?

Comment: @EvertonGouveia vc tem um controller? ele deve fazer a consulta e passar o resultado para a view imagino que seja o `posts_list.php` lá faça o foreach. Na [documentação](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html) tem um hello world de como vc deve utiliza-lo

Answer (score 0):

não ficou muito claro sua questão, mas vamos lá, vc precisa conectar no banco de dados **"site"**, faça assim, tentarei demonstrar da forma mais simples:

```
try {
        $usuario = 'site';
        $host = 'SEU HOST(se for interno é LOCALHOST)';
        $login = 'LOGIN(geralmente o ROOT)';
        $senha = 'SENHA';
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$usuario;host=$host", "$login", "$senha");
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    }
```

Para dar o SELECT na tabela posts:

```
 $sql = "SELECT id, updated, title, description, link, image FROM posts LIMIT 3";
    $sql = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sql->execute();
    $retorno = $sql->fetchAll();
    $quantidadeRegistros = $sql->rowCount();//TEM QUE SER 3, POR TER LIMIT 3
```

após isso você tem que manipular o array **retorno** onde você precisa, por exemplo em uma lista no seu caso na list-inline por exemplo, como você está usando basicamente PHP e mysql vou demonstrar assim:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
```

adicionando assim:

```
   foreach($retorno as $valores){
$image = $valores['image'];  echo "<li>Sua imagem: $image</li>";  }
```