# Problema com MySQL descontinuado para MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou com um problema em meu site, tudo começou depois que eu recebi uma mensagem de descontinuação do MySQL, e pediram para eu alterar para MySQLi, apos eu alterar uma série de códigos apareceram em minha página, o que eu devo fazer para reparar os erros?

O erro inicial era, o seguinte:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   /home/vagalume/public_html/decor/system/database/mysql.php on line 6
>   Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   /home/vagalume/public_html/decor/system/database/mysql.php:6) in
>   /home/vagalume/public_html/decor/system/library/session.php on line
>   11Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter -
>   headers already sent (output started at
>   /home/vagalume/public_html/decor/system/database/mysql.php:6) in
>   /home/vagalume/public_html/decor/system/library/session.php on line
>   11Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/vagalume/public_html/decor/system/database/mysql.php:6) in
>   /home/vagalume/public_html/decor/system/library/currency.php on line
>   45

---

O código que tenho actualmente:

```
<?php
final class MySQL {
    private $link;

    public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
        if (!$this->link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)) {
            trigger_error('Error: Could not make a database link using ' . $username . '@' . $hostname);
        }

        if (!mysql_select_db($database, $this->link)) {
            trigger_error('Error: Could not connect to database ' . $database);
        }

        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $this->link);
        mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $this->link);
        mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION=utf8", $this->link);
        mysql_query("SET SQL_MODE = ''", $this->link);
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        if ($this->link) {
            $resource = mysql_query($sql, $this->link);

            if ($resource) {
                if (is_resource($resource)) {
                    $i = 0;

                    $data = array();

                    while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
                        $data[$i] = $result;

                        $i++;
                    }

                    mysql_free_result($resource);

                    $query = new stdClass();
                    $query->row = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : array();
                    $query->rows = $data;
                    $query->num_rows = $i;

                    unset($data);

                    return $query;  
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                trigger_error('Error: ' . mysql_error($this->link) . '<br />Error No: ' . mysql_errno($this->link) . '<br />' . $sql);
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

    public function escape($value) {
        if ($this->link) {
            return mysql_real_escape_string($value, $this->link);
        }
    }

    public function countAffected() {
        if ($this->link) {
            return mysql_affected_rows($this->link);
        }
    }

    public function getLastId() {
        if ($this->link) {
            return mysql_insert_id($this->link);
        }
    }   

    public function __destruct() {
        if ($this->link) {
            mysql_close($this->link);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Coloque parte do código fonte. Relacionado: [migrar mysql_* para mysqli_*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32820/91)

Comment: Se você está usando mysqli, não deveria estar chamando a função mysql_connect, que causa o primeiro erro. E resolvendo o primeiro, os demais erros que você citou também vão sumir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma parte do seu código que ainda está usando o mysql, e precisa ser atualizado.
Muitas alterações foram adicionadas.
Favor olhar o arquivo `/home/vagalume/public_html/decor/system/database/mysql.php on line 6`.

Abaixo segue um exemplo das funções que devem ser usadas no mysqli.

```
    <?php

    $link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'loja');

    if (!$link) {
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                . mysqli_connect_error()); }

   $query = "INSIRA AQUI SUA SQL" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));  
   $result = $link->query($query); 
   if ($result = $link->query($query))  var_dump(mysqli_fetch_array($result));   

    mysqli_close($link);
```

Esse é um arquivo básico de configuração para o banco de dados.

Comment: eu não conheço de php, o desenvolvedor do meu site, sumiu e eu estou me virando da forma que eu posso, mais esta dificil.
Este valor que esta descrito acima eu encontro no meu Mysql?

Comment: você tem acesso a exibir esse aquivo? /home/vagalume/public_html/decor/system/database/mysql.php. Digo o mysql.php que está nesse caminho acima?

Comment: Tenho sim esta aberto em meu editor

Comment: você poderia exibir ele aqui ou em algum lugar.Pode apagar os dados de usuario e senha antes.

Comment: nao aparece a opção de usuario e senha!

Comment: eu vou responder a minha propria pergunta com o codigo,

Comment: Visualizou o codigo?

Comment: isso é tudo que existe nesse arquivo?

Comment: sim o engraçado é que eu tenho a loja ja a 2 anos e do nada parou, ela é feita no opencart

Comment: mandei o arquivo como resposta. Favor usá-lo com atenção.

Comment: o erro que deu agora foi este:
 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in /home/vagalume/public_html/decor/system/database/mysql.php on line 18

Comment: fiz algumas alterações. Olhe agora.

Comment: adicionei mais uma correção. favor atualizar seu arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

Baseado no arquivo que você mandou, eu alterei as funcões mysql para mysqli.
Segue abaixo.

Favor substituir pelas suas de modo cirúrgico. Mas antes de alterar, faça uma cópia do seu arquivo mysql.php original.

```
   <?php

final class MySQL {

    private $link;

    public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {


        if (!$this->link = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database)) {
            trigger_error('Error: Could not make a database link using ' . $username . '@' . $hostname);
        }

        mysqli_query($this->link,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        mysqli_query($this->link,"SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
        mysqli_query($this->link,"SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION=utf8");
        mysqli_query($this->link,"SET SQL_MODE = ''");

    }

    public function query($sql) {
        if ($this->link) {

            $resource =  $this->link->query($sql);

            if ($resource) {
                if (is_resource($resource)) {
                    $i = 0;

                    $data = array();

                    while ($result = $resource->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $data[$i] = $result;

                        $i++;
                    }

                    mysqli_free_result($resource);

                    $query = new stdClass();
                    $query->row = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : array();
                    $query->rows = $data;
                    $query->num_rows = $i;

                    unset($data);

                    return $query;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                trigger_error('Error: ' .  mysqli_error($this->link) . '<br />Error No: ' . mysqli_error($this->link) . '<br />' . $sql);
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

    public function escape($value) {
        if ($this->link) {
            return mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->link,$value);
        }
    }

    public function countAffected() {
        if ($this->link) {
            return mysqli_affected_rows($this->link);
        }
    }

    public function getLastId() {
        if ($this->link) {
            return mysqli_insert_id($this->link);
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        if ($this->link) {
            mysqli_close($this->link);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Desculpe a demora, tive problemas com algumas vendas realizadas em meu site, como eu nao tenho mais acesso ao painel de controle tive q estornar as vendas.
Mais muito obrigado pela ajuda meu amigo, agora aparece outro erro to achando que o melhor é eu comeár uma nova loja do zero, para agilizar o problema.