# Erro "The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future"

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou com um problema de conexão com banco de dados MySQL com PHP estou utilizando o WAMP criei uma base de dados no meu PHPMyAdmin fiz minha conexão via PHP porem aparece esse erro quando clico em enviar no meu `form`:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

[image: Deprecated: mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future]

Esses são os códigos da minha conexão:

#### config.php

```
<?php
    $db['server']   ='localhost';
    $db['user']     ='felipe';
    $db['password'] ='lalala';
    $db['dbname']   ='base_teste';

    //estabelece uma conexao com server de bd ('servidor', 'usuario', 'senha')
    $conn = mysql_connect($db['server'],$db['user'],$db['password']);

    //conexao com banco
    mysql_select_db($db['dbname'],$conn);
?>
```

#### funcoes.php

```
<?php
    function adicionar($nome,$idade){
        $sql = "insert into tb_alunos (nome,idade) values ('$nome','$idade')";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
?>
```

#### adiciona.php

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';
    include 'funcoes.php';

    adicionar ($_REQUEST['nome'],$_REQUEST['idade']);
?>
```

#### index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>conexao teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="adiciona.php" method="post">
        nome <input type="text" name="nome">
        Idade <input type="text" name="idade">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: vc deve trocar as funções mysql_* por mysqli ou PDO. Tem algumas respostas, com [PDO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91), com [MySQLi](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32820/91)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Está dizendo para você não usar mais estas funções baseadas na extensão antiga que dá acesso ao MySQL. Você deve trocar para a extensão [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Também pode trocar para a PDO, mas [não aconselho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401729/101).

[Tem informações aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/101). Veja um [exemplo de como trocar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47880/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: pelo que vi e so mudar mysli para mysqli

Comment: mudei aqui e nao funcionou mesmo assim sou muito inexperiente no php minha primeira conexão com banco de dados porque depois vou etr que fazer um log para outra aplicação ja pronta estou estudando vc poderia me fazer uma simulação de como ficaria o código

Comment: É, não é só mudar uma letra, tem que estudar a documentação, ver os exemplos, ler a troca que eu já fiz para outro usuário. Não existe mágica em programação. Existe esforço e aprendizado. Aqui não é um local para pedir para as pessoas fazerem para você, aqui apenas esclarecemos dúvidas. Como um usuário já pediu para mostrar como faz a conversão, qualquer outro pedido neste sentido seria considerado duplicata.

Comment: Porque não aconselha a usar o PDO? Com ele você pode usar o mesmo código para vários bancos de dados, e ainda possui prepared statement, que dificulta a realização do ataque SQL injection na sua aplicação.

Comment: @AndréRamos MSQLi também tem. E porque você quer usar vários banco de dados? A não ser que esteja fazendo um desses softwares genéricos para outras pessoas personalizarem é praticamente impossível precisar outro banco de dados. Procure saber sobre as desvantagens do PDO também, não olhe só para **a** vantagem (discutível) dele.

Comment: @bigown Eu acho vantajosos dar a liberdade para o cliente poder mudar o SGBD para um de sua preferência sem se preocupar com o código já escrito. A única desvantagem que eu encontro ao usar o PDO, é a sua performance  comparada com ao MySQLi, que nem é tão gritante assim.

Comment: Mas existe outras. Você pode ter a opinião que quiser sobre isto ser vantajoso ou não, mas o simples fato de você falar que isto é bom sem ter um caso concreto é escolher a ferramenta antes de ver qual é o problema. De qualquer forma aqui não é local para debates.

Comment: @bigown Na verdade, depende da aplicação em que o amigo está desenvolvendo. Se for algo que não exige tanto do servidor e não necessita de uma alta performance, não vejo o porque não usar o PDO. Desculpe-me se passei má impressão nos meus comments anteriores, o meu objetivo não foi apontar qual é o melhor, e sim apontar oque me parecia mais adequado para a situação do autor da pergunta.

Comment: @AndréRamos Eu entendo, não se preocupe. Mas é o contrário. Se não precisa da única coisa que ele faz de bom, não tem porque usar. Usar por usar, usar porque alguém disse para usar, porque todo mundo usa sem saber porque está usando, não é motivo plausível. Vou encerrar porque estamos saindo do propósito do site. E existe vários motivos para não usar o PDO, mas também não é o foco desta pergunta. Se quiser faça uma sobre isto.

Answer (score 4):

Utilize    Msqli

Documentação:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 4):

Funções mysql_* estão obsoletas desde o PHP 5.5. Prefira usar MySQLi ou PDO (acredite, vai ser muito mais vantajoso).

"não devemos usar funções da extensão "mysql" pelo seu desenvolvimento ter sido descontinuado; a extensão vai se tornar obsoleta em breve, ou seja, código que utilize essas funções não irá funcionar em futuras versões do PHP."

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Além disso, mysqli é bem parecido com mysql_* então não irá ter nenhum tipo de problema para aprender e migrar seus projetos. Exemplo:

```
// Conexão mysql
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

// Conexão mysqli
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

funções MySQLi acabam sendo mais novas, rápidas e seguras, possuem novas funções e são orientadas a objetos, ou seja, é uma evolução da extensão mysql_*.

Ainda há outra alternativa para o mysql_* e mysqli, o PDO. Ele permiti trabalhar múltiplos bancos de dados e possui [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) (que não é tão veloz, mas muito mais seguro).

Mesmo o PDO sendo muito criticado, por trazer mais problemas do que soluções. Na minha opnião, eu escolheria ele por ter suporte á mais drivers de BD e por ser muito mais seguro.

Comment: Aviso aos leitores, o "acredite, vai ser muito mais vantajoso" é um absurdo sem tamanho. Em MySQL o PDO praticamente só tem desvantagens.

Answer (score 4):

Muitas vezes, ao procurar ajuda nos sites do internet, eles dão exemplos como você viu, usando tecnologias antigas que já foram descontinuados.

O `mysql_connect()`, e todos os funções `mysql_*` cabem nisso. São descontinuados, mas não quer dizer que todos os sites de tutoriais foram atualizados.

Você vai querer usar, como já explicado, a nova forma:

```
$db = mysqli_connect(...); // Repara o i depois do mysql
```

Answer (score -3):

Tente o seguinte

```
<?php

function db(){
 $con = mysqli_connection("lacalhost", "user", "pass", "db");
 return $con;
}

?>
```