# Erro insert PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tendo um problema ao inserir dados no banco de dados, ja verifiquei se existe algum campo onde não está aceitando valor nulo, porem está tudo ok, ao aparecer o erro é informado o seguinte código:

> Array ( [type] => 8192 [message] => mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead [file] => /var/www/html/jribeirocomunicacoes.com.br/web/admin/includes/conexao.php [line] => 7 )

Meu código está o seguinte.

```
<?php

// incluindo o arquivo que faz a conexao com o banco
include ("../includes/conexao.php");
include ("../includes/suc_validacao.php");
include ("../includes/suc.php");

$nome = $_POST['TXT_NOMEX_CLIEN'];
$mensagem = $_POST['MEM_APRES_CLIEN'];
$naturalidade = $_POST['TXT_NATUR_CLIEN'];
$nacionalidade = $_POST['TXT_NACIO_CLIEN'];
$dtnasc = $_POST['DAT_NASCI_CLIEN'];
$dtnasc = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $dtnasc)));
$ocupacao = $_POST['TXT_OCUPA_ATUAL'];
$clube = $_POST['TXT_NOMEX_CLUBE'];
$desde = $_POST['TXT_DATAX_ADMIS'];
$desde = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $desde)));
$altura = $_POST['TXT_ALTUR_CLIEN'];
$altura = str_replace(",", ".", $altura);
$peso = $_POST['TXT_PESOX_CLIEN'];
$peso = str_replace(",", ".", $peso);
$gostede = $_POST['TXT_GOSTO_CLIEN'];
$naogostade = $_POST['TXT_NGOST_CLIEN'];
$twitter = $_POST['TXT_ENDER_TWITR'];
$facebook = $_POST['TXT_ENDER_FACEB'];
$youtube = $_POST['TXT_ENDER_YOUTB'];
$menuvinc = $_POST['P_COD_IDENT_MENUX'];
$usurLoga = $_SESSION['UsuarioID'];

$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_CLIENTES (COD_IDENT_MENUX, TXT_NOMEX_CLIEN, MEM_APRES_CLIEN, FLG_TIPOX_CLIEN, COD_IDULT_ATUAL, DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL) VALUES";
$query .= "('$menuvinc', '$nome','$mensagem','F', '$usurLoga', now())";

$inserir = mysql_query($query)
        or die("teste");

$COD_IDENT_ULTIM_CLIEN = mysql_insert_id();

$query2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_CLIENTES_PF (COD_IDENT_CLIEN, TXT_NATUR_CLIEN, TXT_NACIO_CLIEN, DAT_NASCI_CLIEN, TXT_OCUPA_ATUAL, TXT_NOMEX_CLUBE, TXT_ALTUR_CLIEN, TXT_PESOX_CLIEN, TXT_ENDER_TWITR, TXT_ENDER_FACEB, TXT_ENDER_YOUTB, TXT_DATAX_ADMIS, TXT_GOSTO_CLIEN, TXT_NGOST_CLIEN, COD_IDULT_ATUAL, DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL) VALUES";
$query2 .= "('$COD_IDENT_ULTIM_CLIEN','$naturalidade','$nacionalidade','$dtnasc','$ocupacao','$clube','$altura','$peso','$twitter','$facebook','$youtube','$desde','$gostede','$naogostade', '$usurLoga', now())";

//executando a query
$inserir = mysql_query($query2)
        or print_r(error_get_last()); die;

$response = array("success" => true);

//fechando a conexao com o banco
mysql_close($conn);

header("Location: listaClientes.php");
exit; // Redireciona o visitante
?>
```

> O erro acontece no segundo die.

Aqui está meu documento que faz a conecção com o banco, no caso o erro está dando por avisar que está obsoleto este documento, como ficaria este mesmo documento passando para PDO ou para mysqli ?

```
<?php

$dbUser = 'dbUSer';
$dbPassword = 'dbPassword';
$dbSite = 'jrcomunicacoes';

$conn = mysql_connect("jrcomunicacoes.mysql.uhserver.com", $dbUser, $dbPassword); // or die ("[HTM]Problema ao conectar ao MYSQL[/HTM]");

if (!$conn) {
    die('[HTM]Problema ao conectar ao MYSQL; erro=' . mysql_error() . '-' . mysql_errno() . '[/HTM]');
}

$db = mysql_select_db($dbSite, $conn); // or die ("[HTM]Problema ao conectar ao banco de dados[/HTM]");

if (!$db) {
    die('[HTM]Problema ao conectar ao banco de dados; erro=' . mysql_error() . '[/HTM]');
}

if (!function_exists('fnc_preparaComando')) {

    function fnc_preparaComando($p_string) {
        return str_replace("'", "\'", $p_string);
    }

}

if (!function_exists('fnc_leituraDB')) {

    function fnc_leituraDB($p_sql) {

        global $w_registro, $numRows;

        $sql = mysql_query($p_sql);

        if (!$sql || ( ( $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0 ) && !$w_registro = mysql_fetch_object($sql) )) {

            $message = '[ERR]LEITURA-DB: ' . mysql_error() . '[/ERR]';

            die($message);
        }
    }
}

// Para retornar valores do banco de dados com a acentuação e pontuação corretamente sem carecteres especiais no lugar
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8");
?>
```

Comment: Erro de conexão com banco de dados

Answer (score 1):

Funções mysql_* estão obsoletas desde o PHP 5.5. Prefira usar MySQLi ou PDO (acredite, vai ser muito mais vantajoso).

"não devemos usar funções da extensão "mysql" pelo seu desenvolvimento ter sido descontinuado; a extensão vai se tornar obsoleta em breve, ou seja, código que utilize essas funções não irá funcionar em futuras versões do PHP."

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Além disso, mysqli é bem parecido com mysql_* então não irá ter nenhum tipo de problema para aprender e migrar seus projetos. Exemplo:

```
// Conexão mysql
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

// Conexão mysqli
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

funções MySQLi acabam sendo mais novas, rápidas e seguras, possuem novas funções e são orientadas a objetos, ou seja, é uma evolução da extensão mysql_*.

Ainda há outra alternativa para o mysql_* e mysqli, o PDO. Ele permiti trabalhar múltiplos bancos de dados e possui [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) (que não é tão veloz, mas muito mais seguro).

Mesmo o PDO sendo muito criticado, por trazer mais problemas do que soluções. Na minha opnião, eu escolheria ele por ter suporte á mais drivers de BD e por ser muito mais seguro.

Comment: Em vez de colocar nova resposta, marque esta como duplicata da outra.

Comment: Você  [tem aqui uma resposta sua exatamente igual](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75815/7210) , o ideal seria criar esta resposta aqui: [Erro de conexão com banco de dados PHPMyAdmin](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75121/erro-de-conex%C3%A3o-com-banco-de-dados-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Já sinalizei a pergunta. @JorgeB.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não seria uma duplicata minha pergunta, porque está funcionando algum insert apenas este que não está, qual motivo do primeiro insert funcionar e o segundo não ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues é verdade que isso possa acontecer. Mas a resposta a pergunta é aquela, o erro quer dizer aquilo mesmo. Além disso você mesmo a considerou duplicata.

Comment: Sim pois não tinha lido totalmente, mais pode me ajudar em que possa ta ocorrendo, pois os outros cadastros funciona perfeitamente.