# Erro no codigo php?

Tags: php, html, sql, banco-de-dados

Olá, estou tentando criar um formulário de cadastro e login. Porém, está dando erro.

Código abaixo:

**formulario_cadastro.php**

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Formulário de Cadastro</title>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Formulário de Cadastro</h2> 
<form name="cadastro" method="post" action="cadastrar.php">

Nome:<br>
<input name="nome" type="text" id="nome" value="<?php echo $nome; ?>" /></br><br>

Sobrenome:<br>
<input name="sobrenome" type="text" id="sobrenome" value="<?php echo $sobrenome; ?>" /></br><br>

Email:<br>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /></br><br>

Nome de Usuário:<br>
<input name="usuarios" type="text" id="usuarios" value="<?php echo $usuario; ?>" /></br><br>

Mais informações sobre você:<br>
<textarea name="info" id="info" value="<?php echo $info; ?>"></textarea></br><br>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enviar" /></br>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

**cadastrar.php**

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$nome = isset( $_POST['nome'] ) ? $_POST['nome'] : 'valor_padrao';
$sobrenome = isset( $_POST['sobrenome'] ) ? $_POST['sobrenome'] : 'valor_padrao';
$email = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? $_POST['email'] : 'valor_padrao';
$usuarios = isset( $_POST['usuarios'] ) ? $_POST['usuarios'] : 'valor_padrao';
$info = isset( $_POST['info'] ) ? $_POST['info'] : 'valor_padrao';


if ((!$nome) || (!$sobrenome) || (!$email) || (!$usuarios)){
echo "ERRO: <br /><br />";
if (!$nome){
echo "Nome é requerido.<br />";
}
if (!$sobrenome){
echo "Sobrenome é requerido.<br /> <br />";
}
if (!$email){
echo "Email é um campo requerido.<br /><br />";
}
if (!$usuarios){
echo "Nome de Usuário é requerido.<br /><br />";
    }
echo "Preencha os campos abaixo: <br /><br />";
include "formulario_cadastro.php";
}else{

$sql_email_check = mysql_query(
"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM usuarios WHERE email='{$email}'"
);
$sql_usuario_check = mysql_query(
"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM usuarios WHERE usuarios='{$usuarios}'"
);
$eReg = mysqli_query( $sql_email_check ) or exit( mysqli_error() );
$uReg = mysqli_query( $sql_usuarios_check ) or exit( mysqli_error() );
$email_check = $eReg[0];
$usuarios_check = $uReg[0];
if (($email_check > 0) || ($usuarios_check > 0)){
echo "<strong>ERRO</strong>: <br /><br />";
if ($email_check > 0){
echo "Este email já está sendo utilizado.<br /><br />";
unset($email);
}
if ($usuarios_check > 0){
echo "Este nome de usuário já está sendo
utilizado.<br /><br />";
unset($usuario);
}
include "formulario_cadastro.php";
}else{



function makeRandomPassword(){
$salt = "abchefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 7){
$num = rand() % 33;
$tmp = substr($salt, $num, 1);
$pass = $pass . $tmp;
$i++;
}
return $pass;
}
$senha_randomica = makeRandomPassword();
$senha = md5($senha_randomica);

$info = htmlspecialchars($info);
$sql = mysql_query(
"INSERT INTO usuarios
(nome, sobrenome, email, usuarios, senha, info, data_cadastro)
VALUES
('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$usuarios', '$senha', '$info', now())")
or die( mysql_error()
);
if (!$sql){
echo "Ocorreu um erro ao criar sua conta, entre em contato.";
}else{
$id = mysql_insert_id();

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "From: Teu Domínio - Webmaster<email@teusite.com.br>";
$subject = "Confirmação de cadastro - teusite.com.br";
$mensagem = "Prezado {$nome} {$sobrenome},<br />
Obrigado pelo seu cadastro em nosso site, <a href='http://www.teusite.com.br'>
http://www.teusite.com.br</a>!<br /> <br />
Para confirmar seu cadastro e ativar sua conta em nosso site, podendo acessar à
áreas exclusivas, por favor clique no link abaixo ou copie e cole na barra de
endereço do seu navegador.<br /> <br />
<a href='http://www.teusite.com.br/ativar.php?id={$id}&code={$senha}'>
http://www.teusite.com.br/ativar.php?id={$id}&code={$senha}
</a>
<br /> <br />
Após a ativação de sua conta, você poderá ter acesso ao conteúdo exclusivo
efetuado o login com os seguintes dados abaixo:<br > <br />
<strong>Usuario</strong>: {$usuarios}<br />
<strong>Senha</strong>: {$senha_randomica}<br /> <br />
Obrigado!<br /> <br />
Webmaster<br /> <br /> <br />
Esta é uma mensagem automática, por favor não responda!";
mail($email, $subject, $mensagem, $headers);
echo "Foi enviado para seu email - ( ".$email." ) um pedido de
confirmação de cadastro, por favor verifique e sigas as instruções!";
}
}
}
?>
```

**Erro:**

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in E:\xampp\htdocs\cadastro\cadastrar.php on line 36
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in E:\xampp\htdocs\cadastro\cadastrar.php on line 36
```

Comment: Você está usando mysql ou mysqli ?

Comment: exatamente isso, como citado acima. Ou você usa mysql ou mysqli(que eu recomendo). Os erros estão acontecendo porque o mysqli exige um parâmetro a mais nas suas funções do que o mysql. Porém para deixar isso certo no seu código todo, use apenas uma das duas, e o recomendado é que use o mysqli, já que o mysql está obsoleto.

Comment: O próprio erro já explica praticamente tudo. Segue a tradução: `Atenção: mysqli_query() espera ao menos 2 parâmetros, apenas 1 foi fornecido em E:\xampp\htdocs\cadastro\cadastrar.php na linha 36` e `Atenção: mysqli_error() espera exatamente 1 parâmetro, nenhum foi fornecido em E:\xampp\htdocs\cadastro\cadastrar.php na linha 36` - Está faltando você por a variável que indica a conexão nos dois casos (obtida no connect() ) - O manual do PHP é seu amigo: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Achei uma postagem aqui do SOpt que eu acredito ser a solução para o problema: **[Atualizar meu código Mysql para Mysqli](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47884/70)**.

Comment: Estou utilizando o mysqli