# Login não funciona

Tags: php, mysql, sql, login

Primeira vez aqui, eu peguei um código pronto adaptei para meu trabalho da faculdade, porém o login não verifica, aceita qualquer coisa que tu coloques.

**Cria login**

```html
<div id="nav">
    <div id="sup_direito">
        <div id="login">
            <input type="text" name="usuario" id="txUsuario" placeholder="login" required>
        </div>
        <div id="senha">
            <input type="password" name="senha" id="txSenha" placeholder="senha" required>
        </div>    
        <input type="submit" value="Entrar" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Código da validação**

```
<?php

// Verifica se houve POST e se o usuário ou a senha é(são) vazio(s)
if (!empty($_POST) AND ( empty($_POST['usuario']) OR empty($_POST['senha']))) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}

// Tenta se conectar ao servidor MySQL
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'usbw') OR trigger_error(mysql_error());
// Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
mysql_select_db('sistemas para internet') OR trigger_error(mysql_error());

$usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);

// Validação do usuário/senha digitados
$sql = "SELECT `cod_login`, `usuario` FROM `login` WHERE (`usuario` = '" . $usuario . "') AND (`senha` = '" . sha1($senha) . "') LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
    // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
    echo "Login inválido!";
    exit;
} else {
// Salva os dados encontados na variável $resultado
    $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

// Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
    if (!isset($_SESSION))
        session_start();

// Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
    $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['cod_login'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['usuario'];


// Redireciona o visitante
    header("Location: restrito.php");
    exit;
}
```

Código restrito

```
<?php
// A sessão precisa ser iniciada em cada página diferente
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

// Verifica se não há a variável da sessão que identifica o usuário
if (!isset($_SESSION['UsuarioID'])) {
    // Destrói a sessão por segurança
    session_destroy();
    // Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
?>
<h1>Página restrita</h1>
<p>Olá, <?php echo $_SESSION['UsuarioNome']; ?>!</p>
```

Comment: Acho melhor procurar um script com as funções `mysqli()` como estes: http://www.eggslab.net/php-login-script/

Comment: Veja mais aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql

Comment: Aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47880/como-atualizar-meu-c%C3%B3digo-mysql-para-mysqli

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida então você acredita que o problema pode ser o jeito que foi escrito o código ou a lógica?

Comment: @GustavoB. tenta pegar com 'mysqli',mas referente a sua pergunta, tenta mudar 'if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {' por 'if (mysql_num_rows($query)<=0){', mas dai onde tem 'echo "login invalido"', vc muda para como tiver dado serto acho q vai funcionar

Comment: @GustavoB. man acho que achei o erro kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk, falto bota o formulario na parte de login muda a parte de <div id="login"> por <form id="login" action="pagina que valida" type="POST">  mas n se esquesa de mudar </div> por </form>

Comment: @Daniel Tranquilo, vou revisar mas me dei conta que não trouxe o note para o Serviço, vou ter que testar esse teus apontamento mais tarde, valeu man pelas dicas

Comment: @Daniel não funcionou :(

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida Obrigado pela dica, consegui resolver

Comment: Infelizmente minha pontuação não permite comentários mas por que o nome da sua database está com espaços ao invés de underline? Usa aspas dupla senão ele não detecta a database direito.

Answer (score -4):

```
      <?php
       session_start(); 
       include("dbconnect.php");

      if (isset($_POST['log_user'])) {
$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['usuario']));
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['senha']));
```

No input submit eu colocaria um name=log_user
datava tbm o dia e horário

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$ahoras = date('H:i:s', time());
$date = date('d-m-Y');

$qry = mysqli_query("select * from login where usuario='$usuario' AND senha='$senha'"); 

$data = mysqli_fetch_array($qry);

$sql = "update login SET ult_login='$date', horas='$ahoras' WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND senha='$senha'"; 

if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){  
         echo"<script></script>";

}else{  
    echo "Update não realizado: ". mysqli_error($conn);  
} 


if (count($errors) == 0) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND senha='$senha'";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($results);
    while($dados = $results->fetch_array()) {
```

No meu eu criei um token no formulário, mesmo estando na página restrita se mudar um só caractere do token que ficará lá em cima na extensão, a sessão é encerrada :)

```
         $usuariouser = $dados['usuario'];
         $senhauser = $dados['senha'];
         $tokenuser = $dados['token'];
         }
    
        if($row == 1) {
      $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuariouser;
      $_SESSION['senha'] = $senhauser;
      $_SESSION['token'] = $tokenuser;

        echo"<script> location.href='/pagina.php?token=$tokenuser';</script>";
    exit();
}else {
echo"<script> location.href='/not_login.php';</script>";

    exit();
    }   
   }
  }
```