# Como esse PHP ficaria convertido em mysqli ao invés de mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Preciso urgente do seguinte PHP que foi construído em msql esteja escrito em mysqli ele faz parte de um aplicativo no qual estou desenvolvendo não tenho conhecimento em PHP já quebrei a cabeça atras de uma conversão e não achei preciso muito de ajuda.

**O Codigo é o seguinte**

```
<?php

$serve = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
if(!$serve){ echo 'erro';}
$db = mysql_select_db('pizzas', $serve);


if($_GET['acao'] == 'listapizzas'){

     $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tipos";

     $re = mysql_query($SQL, $serve);

     $num = mysql_num_rows($re);

     if($num > 0){

           while($Linha = mysql_fetch_object($re)){
                  echo "{$Linha->Nome}<br />";
           }

      }
      else{
          echo 'nenhuma pizza cadastrada';
      }
}
?>
```

Comment: Essa pergunta pode ajudar você: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47880/como-atualizar-meu-código-mysql-para-mysqli não é nada difícil!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqli_* funciona como objeto. Da uma olhada no manual para você entender: [Manual MySQLI](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
     <?php

    $serve = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'senha','banco'); // Se vc indica o banco aqui não precisa selecionar depois

if($_GET['acao'] == 'listapizzas'){

     $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tipos";

     $result = $serve->query($SQL, $result);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)<0){
        printf("Sem registros!");
    } else {
        // Laço
         while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
             printf("%s\n",$obj->nome); 
         }

          mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Perfeito cara!!! vlw msm so não ta 100% pois ainda ta dando isso: warning: mysqli_num_rows(): Fuction cannot be used with MYSQL_USE_RESULTin

Comment: corrigi o erro agora ta 100% so foi trocar MYSQL_USE_RESULT por $result

Comment: Não precisa usar como objeto, pode usar funcional como usava a mysql_, só acertar os parâmetros.