# Erro no envio de dados do formulário

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou aprendendo mysql e php, mas está dando um erro no formulário, onde mesmo tendo sido preenchido ele continua pedindo para preencher os campos e não registra nada na tabela de banco de dados

```
<?php
$db = "progdesenv";
@mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db ($db); 
 ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Nome:<input type="text" name="nome"><br>
   Idade:<input type="text" name="idade"><br>
   Telefone:<input type="text" name="telefone"><br>
   Mensagem<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1" cols="30" rows="10" ></textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="enviado">
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar Informações">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'enviado'){

        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $idade = $_POST['idade'];
        $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
        $editor1 = $_POST['editor1'];

        if(empty($nome) || ($idade) || ($telefone) || ($editor1)){
                echo "Preencha os campos corretamente";
            }else{
                $insereDados = msql_query("INSERT INTO formulario (nome, idade, telefone, editor1) VALUES ('$nome', '$idade', '$telefone', '$editor1' )");  
                echo "Enviado com sucesso!!";
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: **NÃO** utilizes as funções da familia `mysql_*`. Utiliza as da familia `mysqli_*` ou PDO. Essa familia de funções foi descontinuada e poderão ser removidas num futuro próximo. E deverias de fazer *escape* aos valores antes de irem para a base de dados. Lê esta resposta a outra pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%c3%a3o-devemos-usar-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-do-tipo-mysql?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

Mude essa linha:

```
if(empty($nome) || ($idade) || ($telefone) || ($editor1)){
```

Para:

```
if(empty($nome) || empty($idade) || empty($telefone) || empty($editor1)){
```

Dessa forma cada variável será checada por empty. O if anterior apenas verificava `$nome` era vazio e se  `$idade`, `$telefone` ou `$editor1` fossem diferente de vazio isso entraria no if pois todos os testes lógicos estõa conectados através do OU(`||`) ou seja uma validor sendo true a condição é satisfeita.

Como ainda está aprendendo, não use as funções mysql_* pois já são obsoletas, prefira o PDO ou mysqli, leitura recomendada:

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)

[Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91)

Comment: Coloquei o seu código e agora da esse erro:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function msql_query() in E:\sites\htdocs\progdesenv2\admin\index.php on line 34

nesse trecho de código:
$insereDados = msql_query("INSERT INTO formulario (nome, idade, telefone, editor1) VALUES ('$nome', '$idade', '$telefone', '$editor1' )");

Comment: @EstenioRibeiroNobrega, é erro sintaxe, o correto é `mysql_query` e não `msql_query` ta faltando um `y` no nome da função :P

Comment: aeee funcionou, só mais uma dúvida, se eu quiser jogar esses dados no html para que o cliente veja os dados inseridos eu faço como?

Comment: @EstenioRibeiroNobrega, pode dar um echo em nas variaveis `$nome, $telefone etc` ou pegar o id inserido com [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) e fazer um select com os dados do banco.

Comment: @EstenioRibeiroNobrega, essa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32820/91) mostra as converter um código mysql_* para mysqli