# Criei um sistema de cadastro usando PHP+MySql aí na hora de executar pede para substituir o MySql por MySqli... Quais eu devo substituir?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = ""; 
$banco = "dbcadastro";
$conexao = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($banco) or die (mysql_error());
//mysql_connect_banco($host, $user, $pass);
?>

<?php
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
$pais = $_POST['pais'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, sobrenome, pais, estado, cidade, email, senha)
 VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$pais', '$estado', '$cidade', '$email', '$senha',)");
?>
```

Comment: Todas as funções `mysql_*` estão depreciadas, você deve substituir todas as chamadas a estas funções.

Comment: [pergunta relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32820/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = ""; 
$banco = "dbcadastro";
$conexao = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$banco);
// verifica a conexao
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Erro ao conectar: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>

<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
    $pais = $_POST['pais'];
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, sobrenome, pais, estado, cidade, email, senha");
}
?>
```

Comment: Grande parte do código deu certo. Mais ta acusando erro nos
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
$pais = $_POST['pais'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

Notice: Undefined index: nome in C:\wamp\www\cadas\cadastrando.php on line 23

Comment: atualizei a resposta. testa agora

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ajudou bastante agora é só inserir os dados na tabela :)