# Deprecated: mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"

$hostname_conecta = "localhost";
$database_conecta = "";
$username_conecta = "";
$password_conecta = "";         

$conecta = mysql_connect($hostname_conecta, $username_conecta, $password_conecta) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

$db = mysql_select_db($database_conecta);

?>
```

Esta dando esse erro:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   /home/u771688126/public_html/painel/conexao/conecta.php on line 17

Comment: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91) e [MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)

Comment: O erro diz que você **DEVE**  troca a API para conexão com o banco de dados. [Aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91) tem mais detalhes sobre o PDO e do [MYSQLi](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32822/91)

Comment: Não precisa usar necessariamente PDO. USe dessa forma: $conexao = mysqli_connect('servidor','usuario','senha','banco'); e nas querys use dessa forma: mysqli_query($conexao, 'Sua query');