# O meu banco de dados está trocando o sobrenome pelo nome cadastrado e não aparece o email

Tags: php, mysql

Arquivo que grava:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>cadastrando...</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$banco = "cadastro";
$conexao=@mysql_connect($host,$user, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($banco) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<?php
$nome=$_POST['Nome'];
$sobrenome=$_POST ['Sobrenome'];
$pais=$_POST['pais'];
$estado=$_POST['estado'];
$cidade=$_POST['cidade'];
$email=$_POST['Email'];
$senha=$_POST['senha'];
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, sobrenome, pais, estado, cidade, email, senha)
VALUES('$nome', '$Sobrenome', '$pais', '$estado', '$cidade', '$Email', '$senha')");
echo "Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!!!"
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Form

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sistema de Cadastro</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="signup" method="post" action="cadastrando.php">
nome: <input type="text" name="nome" /> </br></br>
sobrenome: <input type="text" name="Sobrenome" /> </br></br>
Pais: <input type="text" name="pais" /> </br></br>
Estado: <input type="text" name="estado" /> </br></br>
Cidade: <input type="text" name="cidade" /> </br></br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="Email" /> </br></br>
Senha: <input type="password" name="senha" /> </br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Primeiramente ajuste os nomes das variáveis no insert: ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$pais', '$estado', '$cidade', '$email', '$senha')

Comment: Sugestão: Caso você esteja populando todos os campos da tabela com as informações, você pode trocar `insert into usuarios(nome, sobrenome, pais, estado...) values(...)` por apenas `INSERT INTO USUARIOS VALUES(....)`. Assim sua query fica mais simplificada, uma vez que você não precisa especificar os campos, já que vai inserir dados em todos eles.

Answer (score 3):

As variáveis no php são case sensitive, maiusculas são diferentede minusculas, logo: `$nome` é diferente de `$Nome`. Os valores enviados pelo form devem ser os mesmos recuperados por `$_POST`, `<input type="text" name="nome" />` é diferente de `$_POST['Nome'];`

Se é iniciando já começou mal, as funções mysql_* já foram descontinuadas e logo serão removidas, use uma API moderna para conexão como o banco de dados como MYSQLi ou PDO.

Sugiro que deixe todos os nomes em caixa baixa,

form

```
nome: <input type="text" name="nome" /> </br></br>
sobrenome: <input type="text" name="sobrenome" /> </br></br>
Pais: <input type="text" name="pais" /> </br></br>
Estado: <input type="text" name="estado" /> </br></br>
Cidade: <input type="text" name="cidade" /> </br></br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /> </br></br>
Senha: <input type="password" name="senha" /> </br></br>
```

cadastra.php

```
//código omitido
$nome = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nome']);
$sobrenome = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST ['sobrenome']);
$pais = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pais']);
$estado = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['estado']);
$cidade = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cidade']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);

$query = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, sobrenome, pais, estado, cidade, email, senha)
          VALUES('$nome', '$Sobrenome', '$pais', '$estado', '$cidade', '$email', '$senha')";

$sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[Como converter uma ligação de MYSQL para MYSQLI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32822/91)

[Usar PDO é a maneira mais segura de se conectar a um BD com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91)

Comment: A culpa talvez nem seja dele, hoje em dia ainda continua a ser mais provável encontrar um tutorial a explicar como conectar usando o _mysql_ em vez do _mysqli_, outra recomendação é colocares na tua resposta, para que ele remova o espaço em `$_POST * ["sobrenome"]`.

Comment: Olhar a data do tutorial é bem importante.

Comment: +1, pelo exemplo, e as recomendações *-*.