# Select com prepared statements MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

//// A conexão é do tipo **MySqli** foi passada pelo método construtor e atribuída a variável **$db;**

```
public function getById($id) {

    $query = $this -> db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = ?");
    $query -> bind_param('i', $id);
    $query -> execute();
    return $query -> fetch();

}
```

Por que o metódo fetch() está retornando um valor booleano? quando dou um var_dump() ele me retorna **true ou 1** Gostaria que o fetch retornasse um array, e como posso escolher o tipo de array? associativo ou de outra forma?

Comment: Se usar simplesmente `return $query->fetch_object();` ou `return $query->fetch_assoc();` não retornaria o que deseja?

Comment: Ele me retorna isso:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_object()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ao utilizar prepared staments com MySQLi em um select, primeiro é necessário passar o resultado do banco para o php, isso é feito com o método/função
[get_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) a grande vantagem dele é o fato de não precisar especificar as colunas individualmente como é feite com [bind_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Altera seu método para:

```
  $query->execute();
  $result = $query->get_result();
  return $result->fetch_all();
}
```

Ou se quiser fazer manualmente.

```
  $query->execute();
  $result = $query->get_result();

  $lista = array();
  while($item = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $lista[] = $item;
  }
  return $lista;
}
```

Depois disso pode obter o resultado com `fetch()` ou variante em um foreach.

**Exemplo com bind_result**

```
public function getById($id) {
   $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT nome, idade, profissao, aniversario
                                FROM pessoas WHERE id = ?");
   $query->bind_param('i', $id);
   $query->execute();
   $query->bind_result($nome, $idade, $profissao, $aniversario);

   $lista = array();
   $i = 0;
   while($query->fetch()){
      $lista[$i]['nome'] = $nome;
      $lista[$i]['idade'] = $idade;
      $lista[$i]['profissao'] = $profissao;            
      $lista[$i]['aniversario'] = $aniversario;
      $i++;
   }
   return $lista;
}
```

Comment: tentei com o get_result e o var_dump não me retorna um array e sim um booleano ainda... mas o bind_result eu terei que fazer sempre manualmente? por exemplo, estou fazendo uma classe Model abstrata, quando eu usava PDO era só dar o fetch que ele me retornava o array e eu pegava fora do escopo do método, quero só retornar o array e manipula-lo fora do método, entende? Obrigado.

Comment: @NGTHM4R3, o MySQLi funciona diferente do PDO, por isso mostrei a diferente entre o `bind_result()` e o `get_result()`. Aleterei a resposta para o método retornar um array no lugar do result.

Comment: Obrigado, eu preciso atribuir a uma variável porque seria o método execute() que possui o restante dos outros métodos como o get_result?

Comment: @NGTHM4R3, o `execute()` manda a sua consulta para o banco, para pegar o retorno vc precisa do `get_result()` ele sim devolve as linhas(resultset) consultadas. Pode notar que fazer um insert/update/delete é bem diferente de um select com prepared statements.

Comment: Entendi, no caso, para fazer o insert/update/delete seria só com o execute, certo? ou eu precisaria do get_result para saber se a query foi bem sucedida.

Comment: No insert/update/delete não precisa do get_result(), so no select mesmo. @ngthm4r3

Comment: Podias também adicionar à tua resposta, uma explicação, de que as _array_ podem ser instanciadas dentro do _loop_ mesmo sem prévias instâncias fora.

Comment: Entendi, aproveitando essa pergunta, como eu conserto a codificação dos caracteres? ele me retorna os caracteres bugados, no PDO eu passava uma variável como opções, mudando o charset para utf8, como eu posso mudar? Obrigado.

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 `$this->db->set_charset("utf8")`.

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 joga esse código na hora de criar o objeto, cria e já seta o o charset, depois passa pra frente a conexão.

Comment: Entendi, consegui, valeu!