# Posso utilizar "mysql_real_escape_string" em site "mysqli_connect"?

Tags: php, mysqli

posso utilizar a função `mysql_real_escape_string` em um site construído em `mysqli_connect`? E se sim faz alguma diferença ou a proteção seria menor?

Ou deveria utilizar `mysqli_escape_string`? Porque quando pus o `mysqli_escape_string` deu uns erros quando foi fazer um `mysqli_query`..

`mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in ....`

POREM  ao usar o `mysql_escape_string` ele retorna

`mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string()`

No cado deveria utilizar `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motivos pelos quais não se deve usar as funções mysql_*, estão obsoletas, removidas do php7, necessita de um conexão mysql_* para funcionar e não resolve o problema de sql injections pois apenas escapas determinados caracteres, para resolver isso utilize prepared statements.

> mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in

Ao utilizar o estilo procedural do mysqli **QUASE SEMPRE** o primeiro argumento da função é conexão.

> string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )

**Leitura Recomendada:**

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91)

[Select com prepared statements MySQLi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93028/91)

[Manual - mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: sempre tem que por a conexão junto? no meu caso >> 
`$painel_log = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['painel_log']);`

Comment: @PedroQuezado, sim sempre, a segunda linha amarela da resposta, mostra a assinatura da função e quantos parâmetros você deve passar ao chamar ela.

Answer (score 3):

Não, não use! A função mysql_real_escape_string está obsoleta.

O certo seria usar:

```
$anything = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['variavel']);
```

Comment: sempre tem que por a conexão junto? no meu caso >> `$painel_log = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['painel_log']);`

Comment: @PedroQuezado Quando as funções mysqli são utilizadas o primeiro argumento é "sempre" a conexão.

Comment: ahhhhh entendiiii

Comment: asauhsuhau VLWWW

Answer (score -1):

Cara, aprenda e utilize o PDO. Já foi lançado o PHP 7, que tornou obsoletas todas as funções mysql_*, tornando incompatível códigos legados. Uma hora você vai ter que lidar com esse problema. O PDO tem um método chamado bindValue que resolve esse problema facinho pra você.