# Erro ao declarar variável em sistema de login

Tags: php, mysql, variáveis, login

Estou fazendo um sistema de login e agora me deparo com um "Notice" que indica que minha Variável não esta definida. Esta variável não é informada pelo formulário. Ela é definida por uma função que vai gerar uma chave. `KeyGenerator()`;

Ja conferi varias vezes e tenho no banco de dados a tabela corretamente. 
Ja olhei todas as formas de declarar uma variável vazia e não consigo tirar o erro. Alguem sabe como fazer?

O erro é dado na linha quando mando inserir os dados no banco:

> "Notice: Undefined variable: userkey in C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\painel\system\database.php
>   on line 7 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@servidor.com, Ana78, 40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef,
>   , 1456576578, 1)' at line 1"

```
<?php 
// CADASTAR O USUARIO
    function Register($name, $mail, $username, $password,  $status = true){
        $password = CryptPassword($password);
        $userKey  = KeyGenerator();
        $register = time();
        $query    = "INSERT INTO membros (name, mail, username, password, userkey, register, status) VALUES ($name, $mail, $username, $password, $userkey, $register, $status)";

        return mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }

// VERIFICA SE LOGIN EXISTE
    function UserNameExists($username){
        $query  = "SELECT username FROM membros WHERE username = '$username'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


// VERIFICA SE EXISTE E-MAIL
    function MailExists ($mail){
        $query  = "SELECT mail FROM membros WHERE mail = '$mail'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

// CONEXAO COM BANCO DE DADOS
    function connect(){
        $conn = mysql_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        if (!$conn)
            die(mysql_error());
            else {
                mysql_select_db(DATABASE, $conn ) or die(mysql_error());

                mysql_query("SET NAME 'utf-8");
                mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8");
                mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8");
                mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8");


            }

    }

 ?>
```

Função:

```
    function KeyGenerator(){
        return rand();
    }
```

Formulário:

```
<?php 
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/painel/system/system.php';
    AccessPublic();
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registar</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Registar</h2>
<hr>


<?php ValidateFormRegister(); ?>

<form action="" method="post">

    <label for="">Nome</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo GetPost('name'); ?>"><br/><br/>

    <label for="">E-Mail</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="mail" value="<?php echo GetPost('mail'); ?>"><br/><br/>

    <label for="">Usuário</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo GetPost('username'); ?>"><br/><br/>

    <label for="">Palavra-Passe</label><br/>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br/><br/>

    <label for="">Confirme a Palavra-Passe</label><br/>
        <input type="password" name="confirm"><br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Registar">

    <a href="<?php echo URL_BASE; ?>">LOGAR-SE</a>




</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há diferença ao usar maiúsculas e minúsculas no nome das variáveis no PHP.

```
$userKey = "exemplo"; // no seu caso: $userKey = KeyGenerator();
echo $userkey; // vai dar erro (K minúsculo), $userkey != $userKey
echo $userKey; // está correto
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php:

> As variáveis no PHP são representadas por um cifrão ($) seguido pelo nome da variável. Os nomes de variável no PHP fazem distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Use `$userKey` e deve funcionar:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO membros (name, mail, username, password, userkey, register, status) VALUES ($name, $mail, $username, $password, $userKey, $register, $status)";
```

Comment: Berriel, só uma dica, seria interessante traduzir a citação em inglês também.

Comment: @DiegoF fiz, tava procurando o link do manual em pt-br para não ter que traduzir com minhas palavras

Comment: +1. seria interessante quem negativou agora falar o que pode ser melhorado. A resposta já foi traduzida e adequada ao site.

Comment: @Diego , muito obrigado, era mesmo isto que estava a gerar o erro da variavel indefinida, uma coisa tão banal de desatenção. mas agora continua o segundo erro: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@hotmail.com, golx, 40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef, a6ea306ef0cd6d8008' at line 1

Comment: Desculpa mais uma vez a simplicidade do caso, neste erro ja vem com os dados do formulario e esta linha 1? onde a acho para verificar o erro de sintax?

Comment: @GOLX esse erro é pq você precisa escapar esses caracteres, como o `@`. Recomendo também não usar as funções `mysql_*`, pois estão depreciadas. Procure no SOpt que você encontrará informações a respeito. Caso minha resposta tenha resolvido o problema da sua pergunta original, marque como resposta, por favor. Caso não encontre a solução para o seu novo problema no SOpt, abra uma nova pergunta com os detalhes necessários, mas acho que você encontrará.

Comment: @berriel, ogd, entao vou procurar alternativa para trocar o mysql_. Agora como neste codigo posso escapar os caracteres? como eu faria isto?

Comment: @GOLX use http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php Não se esqueça de marcar essa resposta como correta ou dar um voto.

Comment: @Berries ainda estou no curso basico de php, desculpa. fiz umas tentativas de escapar mas em vao, o segundo erro continua.Pode me dar um exemplo de como ficaria neste meu codigo por favor?

Comment: @GOLX a política do SOpt desencoraja esse tipo de atitude, visto que uma solução dada em um comentário dificilmente pode ser encontrada por outros usuários e assim não teria muito propósito. Recomendo que veja isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103046/posso-utilizar-mysql-real-escape-string-em-site-mysqli-connect Caso não encontre o que busca, você pode abrir uma nova pergunta