# Por que minha query não está funcionando com a variável php

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com problemas com minha *query* do *mysql*. O valor é passado do formulário php corretamente com o `$_POST`, porém quando adiciono a variável para fazer a comparação a query não envia uma resposta, mas se adiciono o valor exato que está no banco eu recebo uma resposta, mas preciso utilizar o valor que vem da variável.

dessa foma funciona

```
//pegar matricula
  $query_matricula = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT matricula FROM usuario where nome = 'Maria'") or die("ERROR" .mysqli_error());
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_matricula);
  $numero_matricula = $row['matricula'];
  echo $row['matricula'];
```

dessa forma não funciona

```
 //pegar matricula
  $query_matricula = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT matricula FROM usuario where nome = '$nome'") or die("ERROR" .mysqli_error());
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_matricula);
  $numero_matricula = $row['matricula'];
  echo $row['matricula'];
```

Comment: Pode ter espaço ai. Recomendado => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93028/91

Comment: mesmo se o nome não tiver espaços ou acentuação, parece que o fato dele estar vindo de outra consulta ao banco está fazendo com que o select não aceite como iguais

Comment: Depois, do `myqli_query()` coloque, `echo 'teste';`, veja se aparece algo na tela.

Comment: Quanndo adiciono o valor manualmente o echo me envia a resposta certa, mas quando coloco a variavel ele não envia nada, como se não achasse o valor igual

Comment: O 'teste' apareceu na tela?

Comment: Coloquei o echo 'teste'; como falou e apareceu: --teste

Comment: Não da para dizer onde exatamente está o erro, tente imprimir a consulta. tente: `$sql = "SELECT matricula FROM usuario where nome = '$nome'";
echo $sql;
$query_matricula = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql) or die("ERROR" .mysqli_error($conexao));`

Comment: Acho que eram os espaços em branco o problema. adicionei uma função para apagar os espaços e ele me enviou a resposta correta. Obrigada pela atenção

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certifique-se que o que vem do post está igual ao conteúdo buscado. Gosto de fazer assim... `echo '-'.$nome.'-';`. Pode ser que tenha espaços no nome. Limpe-os: `$nome = trim( $_POST[ 'nome' ] );`.

Comment: Adicionei a função para apagar os espaços e resoleu. Obrigada.

Comment: Foi um prazer ajudá-la

Answer (score -1):

tente desta forma

```
$query_matricula = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT matricula FROM usuario where nome = '{$nome}'") or die("ERROR" .mysqli_error());
```