# Como usar o mysql_result com o MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Gostaria de saber como usar o `mysql_result` no `mysqli` não estou conseguindo, estava olhando o site `php.net` e a unica coisa que vi foi um `mysqli_data_seek` se alguém puder me ajudar...

Código que eu gostaria de passar para `mysqli`:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_produto = $id");
if($id!=""){
     $descricao = mysql_result($sql,0,"descricao");
     $nome = mysql_result($sql,0,"nome");
     $preco = mysql_result($sql,0,"preco");
     $img = mysql_result($sql,0,"img");
}
```

Comment: É impossível! essa função não existe, precisa trabalhar de outra forma

Comment: eu vi esse tal de mysli_data_seek rray mas n intendi muito bem ele

Comment: seria esse o novo metodo que e igual ao mysql_result?

Comment: Pode usar assim => [Select com prepared statements MySQLi](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93036/91)

Comment: no meu caso entao eu teria que usar o bind que voce falou no topico?

Comment: Sim, isso evite sql injection

Comment: intao no meu ficaria assim?   $lista = array();
   $i = 0;
   while($query->fetch()){
      $lista[$i]['descricao'] = $descricao;
      $lista[$i]['nome'] = $nome;
      $lista[$i]['preco'] = $preco;            
      $lista[$i]['img'] = $img;
      $i++;                                                                                                              aqui entraria o print que tem dentro do meu if? e tambem eu esqueco meu if?
   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe nenhuma função chamada `mysqli_result()`, utilize `mysqli_fetch_*()` no lugar, isso elimina todas essas atribuições de variáveis. Evite sql injections usando prepared statements.

Com prepared statements você precisa definir os tipos parâmentros enviados na consulta, `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` faz isso, `mysqli_stmt_execute()` executa a consulta no banco, `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` obtem a reposta do banco e `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` pega essa infomação e devolve na forma de um array associativo, esse código está no estilo procedural.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_produto = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['nome'] .' - '. $row['descricao'] .' - '. $row['preco']. '<br>';
}
```

Comment: uma outra perg que surgiu no meu caso eu teria que mostrar o nome dos respectivos assim como a img e a descricao entao tipo dentro do echo que eu quero exivir o nome eu tria que colocar echo $row['nome'];?

Comment: @LeonardoCosta isso mesmo

Comment: mas eu fiz assim e nao consigo chamar o produto e agr tentei de outro jeito e nao chama o produto tbm tipo la no meu getch na url ele ta passando o id certo mas ele nao chama a img o preco a descricao daqueel produto

Comment: opss desculpa pelo comentario kkkkkkk tinha um pequeno erro conexao com o banco nao estava chamando desculpe

Comment: agora foi obg pela resposta rray