# Mysqli Prepare com loop para Select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Estou tentando fazer um `SELECT` utilizando `MySQLi` e `PREPARE` em um `FOR` mas não funcionando. Sempre está retornando um único zero.

Código da Aplicação:

```
if( $teste = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_CONTATOS, `data` AS DATA_CONTATO FROM `contatos` WHERE `data` >=? AND `data` <=?") )
{

    $mes = date("m");
    $ano = date("Y");

    $data_start = "01-".$mes."-".$ano;

    $tempo_start = strtotime($data_start);
    $tempo_end = strtotime("+1 month", $tempo_start);

    for( $i = $tempo_start; $i < $tempo_end; $i += 86400 )
    {
        $teste->bind_param( 'ss', date('Y-m-d', $i), date('Y-m-d', $tempo_end) );
        $teste->execute();
        $teste->bind_result( $totalcontato, $data_contato);
        $teste->store_result();
    }

    while( $teste->fetch() )
    {
        echo $totalcontato ." | ". $data_contato;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bacco Era para retornar todos os dias do mês com os valores. Mesmo que se o valor for 0.

Comment: o que tem na sua variavel $teste? tente remove-la e veja qual o resultado...

Comment: Joga o while pra dentro do for, deve imprir algo diferente

Comment: @rray Imprimiu alguns dados. Obrigado, com isso fiz algumas alterações e ficou como eu queria. Vou responder a pergunta.

Comment: Legal que conseguiu resolver :D. Só para deixar registrado, odeio `bind_result()`

Comment: @rray você usa o que no lugar ou não `PREPARE`? Por que, olha é bem chato, tem que valer a pena na performance.

Comment: Quando possível uso `get_result()` [veja a diferença](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93036/91), mas você precisa ficar esperto pq `get_result()` depedende do mysqlnd, se ele não estiver instalado no seu host de produção, só resta o `bind_result()` mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a ajuda do @rray que sugeriu colocar o `while` dentro do `for` e alguns ajuste cheguei a o resultado que eu desejava.

Segue o `SCRIPT` para que possa ajudar alguém com o mesmo problema:

```
if( $teste = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_CONTATOS FROM `contatos` WHERE `data` >=? AND `data` <=?") )
{

    $mes = date("m");
    $ano = date("Y");

    $data_start = "01-".$mes."-".$ano;

    $tempo_start = strtotime($data_start);
    $tempo_end = strtotime("+1 month", $tempo_start);

    for( $i = $tempo_start; $i < $tempo_end; $i += 86400 )
    {
        $teste->bind_param( 'ss', date('Y-m-d', $i), date('Y-m-d', $i) );
        $teste->execute();
        $teste->bind_result($totalcontato);
        while( $teste->fetch() )
        {
            echo $totalcontato ." | ". date('Y-m-d', $i);
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }

}
```

> OUTPUT

```
0 | 2016-01-01
0 | 2016-01-02
4 | 2016-01-03
4 | 2016-01-04
6 | 2016-01-05
6 | 2016-01-06
0 | 2016-01-07
0 | 2016-01-08
4 | 2016-01-09
7 | 2016-01-10
6 | 2016-01-11
5 | 2016-01-12
5 | 2016-01-13
0 | 2016-01-14
0 | 2016-01-15
8 | 2016-01-16
10 | 2016-01-17
9 | 2016-01-18
6 | 2016-01-19
0 | 2016-01-20
0 | 2016-01-21
0 | 2016-01-22
5 | 2016-01-23
8 | 2016-01-24
7 | 2016-01-25
6 | 2016-01-26
0 | 2016-01-27
0 | 2016-01-28
0 | 2016-01-29
0 | 2016-01-30
0 | 2016-01-31
```

Com isso cheguei ao total de contatos por dia do mês atual, mesmo que o valor seja zero,  de forma dinâmica. Espero ajudar alguém.