# Pagina de login utilizando mysqli_fetch_row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou criando uma página bastante simples de login onde o usuário digite o seu nome e senha, o sistema faz varredura no banco de dados(mysql) e valida sua entrada, porém, quando eu entro com os valores corretamente o sistema retorna null.

Segue o código html

```
<html> 
    <body> 
        <h3>UP Consultoria</h3> 
        <p>Faça seu login</p> 
        <form  method="post" action="teste.php"  id="searchform"> 
          <input  type="text" name="name"> 
          <input  type="text" name="password">
          <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Entrar"> 
        </form> 
      </body> 
    </html> `

Segue o código php:

    <?php
      if(empty($_POST['name']) or empty($_POST['password'])){
        echo "Digite valores válidos";
      }else{
      $nome=$_POST['name'];
      $senha=$_POST['password'];
      $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','Upconsul') or die (mysql_error());
      if($resultado = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT nome FROM usuarios WHERE nome=$nome",MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)){
            printf ("%s/n" ,$row[0]);
        }
        mysqli_free_result($resultado);
        }
    mysqli_close($link);
    }     
?>
```

Tenho certeza que é alguma coisa bem banal, se puderem me ajudar fico grato. Estou usando phpmyadmin para simular o servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize prepared statements, para evitar sql injections e não armaze senhas como texto puro.

Ao usar passa os valores diretamente na consulta os valores string(varchar e outros do tipo texto) necessecitam de aspas simples.

```
mysqli_query($link,"SELECT nome FROM usuarios WHERE nome = '$nome'")
```

Leitura recomendada:

[Select com prepared statements MySQLi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93036/91)