# Sistema de Login - PHP e JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Oi, estou fazendo um sistema de login e estou com dúvidas na segurança dele, ele é bem simples e faz o Ajax pela JQuery de uma página PHP com MySQL, o código é esse:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="teste.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="loginUsuario" id="loginUsuario" class="input" value="NOME DE USÚARIO">
    <input type="text" name="loginSenha" id="loginSenha" class="input" value="SENHA">
    <input type="submit" name="loginEntrar" id="loginEntrar" class="input" value="ENTRAR">
</form>
```

**JQuery:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#loginEntrar").click(function() {
        var loginLogin = $("#loginUsuario").val();
        var loginSenha = $("#loginSenha").val();
        $("#loginEntrar").prop('disabled', true);
        $.post('login.php', {
            login: loginLogin,
            senha: loginSenha
        }, function(resposta) {
            if (resposta == true) {
                $("#loginForm").submit();
            }
        }, 'html');
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

**PHP:
login.php**

```
<?php

include "bd_connect.php";

$login=$_POST['login'];
$senha=$_POST['senha'];


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE login LIKE '$login' AND senha LIKE '$senha'") or die(mysql_error());
$totalres = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($totalres == 1)
{
echo true;
}
else
{
echo false;
}

?>
```

Como faço a tradução do MySQL para mysqli e sobre esse método de login, é seguro ?

Comment: Qual a dúvida que está tendo?

Comment: Sobre a segurança do login!

Comment: São duas duvidas muito amplas de se responder, na minha opinião.

Comment: Posso responder com um simples: não  ?

Comment: Essa sua pergunta está muito ampla. De qualquer forma, o essencial já foi respondido aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3571

Comment: Para complementar: a senha não é criptografada no banco, um select * from usuarios e tenho user e senha do sistema todo. O input da senha é um campo texto... se eu estiver atrás de alguém posso ver a senha da pessoa no monitor... Enfim, comece pelo link enviado pelo @Bacco

Comment: Isso aqui pode ajudar [Select com prepared statements MySQLi](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93028/91). Mas não use algo como `like senha`...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL para MySQLI muda pouca coisa, no máximo a chamada da função se não me engano.

Agora login na consulta usando LIKE? Minha sugestão é deixar com = e criptografar as senhas do banco com md5.

No arquivo que você faz conexão ao banco, uma maneira de se precaver também é percorrendo todos os posts e get verificando se não há caracteres maliciocos de inject... São todas precauções boas de se tomar

Answer (score 0):

Para mysqli poderá fazer da seguinte maneira:

```html
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "login", "senha", "bd");

$verifica = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from users WHERE id='$id'");
```

Dei um exemplo, agora é aplicar ao seu caso.