# Consulta mysql não está dando retorno

Tags: php, mysqli

eu tenho uma database **Cadastro**
com duas tabelas **joao** e **maria**
contendo duas colunas **nome** e **idade** e estou querendo fazer uma consulta em php só não sei se estou fazendo certo porqque faz tempo que eu uso banco de dados eu tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
<?php
        
  $host = 'localhost';
  $user = 'devel';
  $password = '********';
  $database = 'Cadastro';
        
  $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die(mysqli_error());
  $consult = $_GET['q'];
            
  if(isset($_GET['q'])){
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Cadastro` WHERE `nome` LIKE $consult");
      echo $sql;
  }                    
  else {
      echo 'nao foi encontrado nada';
  }
?>
```

eu nao estou recebendo nenhum retorno

[image]
[image]
[image]

ja existe dados na colunas mas nao esta retornando nada

Comment: Ta faltando coisa nessa código, um `i` no `mysql_query()` e pegar o resultado da consulta com um while & `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Como disse o @rray: `$result = mysqli_query( $connect, "SELECT * FROM ...` e `print_r( mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result  ) )` pra ver o retorno. Gostei dos nomes do exemplo :) "João e Maria" são nomes bem didáticos pra exemplos aqui do site.

Comment: E antes que apaguem todo o seu DB, `$consult = mysql_real_escape_string( $conexao, $_GET['q'] );`

Comment: acho que minha consuta esta errada nao esta retornando nada ainda existe alguma manera de saber se minha consuta foi realizada com suceso?

Comment: Não está nem sendo realizada, tem que corrigir os erros graves antes. Releia os comentários anteriores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente os erros não estão sendo exibidos.

Caso esteja em um ambiente de desenvolvimento (não público), pode alterar o seu arquivo `php.ini` mudando:

- onde há `display_errors = off` altere para `display_errors = on`
- onde há `display_startup_errors = off` altere para `display_startup_errors = on`.
- onde há `error_reporting = QUALQUER_COISA` altere para `error_reporting = E_ALL`

Recomendo que dê uma lida em [Configurações em Execução do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php)

Além disso, como a busca é por uma string, a mesma, no seu caso a variável `$consult`, deverá estar entre aspas:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Cadastro` WHERE `nome` LIKE '$consult'");
```

Espero ter ajudado e desejo boa sorte em seu projeto!

Answer (score 0):

Ao utilizar o MySQLi lembre-se de qua maioria das funções o primeiro argumento é a conexão e não esqueça do `i` no final.

O `isset` deve ser chamado antes de utilizar alguma chave do array e não depois do contrario vai gerar um warning.

Sempre usa função `mysqli_error($conexao)` em conjunto `mysqli_query()` para retornar os erros de alguma consulta para facilitar a correção do problema.

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
$consult = isset($_GET['q']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['q']) : '';

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `Cadastro` WHERE `nome` LIKE %$consult%") or die(mysqli_error($connect);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $row['nome'] .' - '. $row['idade'] .'<br>';
}
```

A solução ideial é trocar o `mysqli_real_escape_string()` por prepared statements, veja como fazer [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93028/91).