# MySQLi não executa insert dentro de uma função

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho essa função:

```
function envia($mensgem) {
    $odb = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE);
    mysqli_query($odb, "INSERT INTO pedidos VALUES ('$mensagem')");
    mysqli_close($odb);
}
```

Uso essa função em outra página chamando ela pelo `require('funcoes/envia.php');`, executo essa função usando `envia('Olá mundo');`, vou ver no phpMyAdmin e não foi registrado nada.

Gostaria que o insert executasse dentro de funções para facilitar :)

PS: Foram definidos corretamente o HOST, USER, PASS e DATABASE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mas não estás a especificar a coluna da mensagem, para que coluna da tabela `pedidos` vai esse texto (`$mensagem`)? Deves especificar:

```
mysqli_query($odb, "INSERT INTO pedidos (<NOME DA COLUNA AQUI>) VALUES ('$mensagem')");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

E devias usar *[prepared statements](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93028/select-com-prepared-statements-mysqli)*, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Opa, valeu! Não pensei que necessitasse informar os nomes das colunas :)

Comment: De nada @GustavoDias

Answer (score -3):

Usa o Mysql_execute($SeuInsert) e no final o mysql_close(SuaConexao);

Comment: Alvaro, o mysqli_execute é usado com mysqli_prepare, e ele está usando mysqli_query. Além disso, não é mysql_, é mysqli_. Funções mysql_ são obsoletas. É legal sua iniciativa em ajudar, mas é importante prestar atenção nestes detalhes para nas próximas postagens ter uma pontuação melhor.