# SELECT ... WHERE nome LIKE bind_param

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-select

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php 
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "minhasenha", "meu_db");

$produto = $_GET['q'];

$produto = '%'.$produto.'%';

$busca_produtos = $link->prepare("SELECT id, nome_com from clientes where nome_com LIKE ?");

$busca_produtos->bind_param("i", $produto);

$busca_produtos->bind_result($id, $nome_com);

$busca_produtos->store_result();

if($busca_produtos->num_rows() == 0){

    echo "Nenhum produto encontrado";

} else{

    while ($busca_produtos->fetch()) {
        echo $nome_com;
    }
}
?>
```

Entretanto, não consigo realizar o `bind_param()` juntamente com o `LIKE` do `SELECT`.
Percebam que declarei a variável `$produto` acima e concatenei com os caracteres `%`, mas mesmo assim retorna a seguinte mensagem

> Nenhum produto encontrado

Queria saber como devo formatar o código de forma correta?

Comment: E por quê está fazendo o `bind_param` com o parâmetro `i`, que representa um valor inteiro? Não deveria ser `s`?

Comment: Fiz a alteração para string, mas mesmo assim continua a não exibir os dados!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não se utiliza o `LIKE` em números (inteiros, double etc) troque o `i` por `s`. Também faltou chamar o método `execute()` após o `bind_param()` pois ele envia a consulta para o banco de dados sem isso não é possível recuperar o resultado.

Seu código deve ficar:

```
$busca_produtos = $link->prepare("SELECT id, nome_com from clientes where nome_com LIKE ?");
$busca_produtos->bind_param("s", $produto);
if(!$busca_produtos->execute()){
   echo $busca_produtos->error;
}

$busca_produtos->bind_result($id, $nome_com);

if($busca_produtos->num_rows() == 0){
    echo "Nenhum produto encontrado";
} else{
    while ($busca_produtos->fetch()) {
        echo $nome_com;
    }
}
```

**Relaciondas:**

[Select com prepared statements MySQLi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93028/91)

[MySQLi fazer bind com um array de valores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101965/91)

Comment: Cara. Muito obrigado. Realmente faltou o $busca_produtos->execute(); - Foi distração.
Na correria a gente acaba esquecendo. Como dizem: o programador precisa de tempo, rs. Grande abraço

Comment: A variável é com aspas não? `$produto = ' "%'.$produto.'%" '`; e faltou o $busca_produtos->execute(); like é string: s

Comment: @IvanFerrer fiz um teste aqui coloquei o coringa direito sem aspas.