# Como faço para exibir uma mensagem se registro encontrado e se não encontrado?

Tags: php, mysql, css, programação-dinâmica

Tenho a seguinte rotina em php:

```
or die ("Não foi possível realizar a consulta ao banco de dados");
while($rowfoto2 = mysql_fetch_array($ridfoto2))
   {
```

Como faço para exibir uma mensagem se registro encontrado e se não encontrado?

Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Veja o número de linhas retornadas, se for zero, `echo 'registro não encontrado';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um pouco mais otimizado mas o que o Bacco respondeu resolve o teu problema.

```
or die ("Não foi possível realizar a consulta ao banco de dados");
if (mysqli_num_rows($ridfoto2) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ridfoto2)) {
     //Instruções
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Resumindo os comments que eu deixei anteriormente: seu código está correto, só não concordo que seja uma otimização do meu, apenas uma reordenação. Entendo que se a mensagem vem no `if` ou no `else` depende apenas da necessidade e/ou conveniência que o autor pretende.

Answer (score 7):

Basicamente é isso:

```
or die ("Não foi possível realizar a consulta ao banco de dados");
if( mysql_num_rows($ridfoto2) == 0 ) {
    echo 'Não veio nada';
} else {
 while($rowfoto2 = mysql_fetch_array($ridfoto2))
    {
```

É o que o @rray disse nos comments.

Importante, já que você está desenvolvendo um código novo, usar as funções `mysqli` no lugar das funções `mysql`, que já estão obsoletas e vão parar de funcionar nas próximas versões do PHP.

Aqui tem uma resposta do @rray que orienta essa troca: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32822/70