# Erro "expects parameter 2 to be resource" ao realizar conexao com o banco

Tags: php, mysql, sql-select

Estou tentando realizar uma conexão via php para um servidor mysql mas sempre apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in /home/u517649386/public_html/conecta.php on line 6

O código usado é o seguinte:

```
<?php
$banco = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql.hostinger.com.br;u517649386_teste', 'u517649386_teste','senha')or die(mysql_error());
print "Conexão efetuada com sucesso!";


mysql_select_db('u517649386_teste', $con);
print "Conexão e Seleção OK!"; 


if($_GET['acao'] == 'listapizzas'){

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `pizzas` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

     $re = mysql_query($SQL, $serve);

     $num = mysql_num_rows($re);

     if($num > 0){

           while($Linha = mysql_fetch_object($re)){
                  echo "{$Linha->Nome}<br />";
           }

      }
      else{
          echo 'nenhuma pizza cadastrada';
      }
}
?>
```

A versão do php do servidor é 5.5.35

Comment: `$con` não deve ter uma conexão vc deveria usar apenas o PDO, as funções `mysql_*` foram removidas da versões mais novas do php

Comment: Ja que as funções 'mysql_*' foram removidas oque posso usar no lugar?

Comment: Use o PDO ou as funções MySQLi, o que muda basicamente é que a conexão deve ser passada como primeiro argumento na maioria das funções, pode olhar [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32822/91)

Comment: Siga os exemplos da documentação amigo, não fique tentando fazer as coisas da cabeça, aprenda como funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variável $con está nula e além disso as funções nativas do mysql não funcionam com PDO. Tente assim: `

```
   <?php

$serve = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'senha','banco'); // Se vc indica o banco aqui não precisa selecionar depois

if ($serve->connect_errno) {
    printf("Erro: %s\n", $serve->connect_error);
    exit();
}


if($_GET['acao'] == 'listapizzas'){

     $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tipos";

     $re = $serve->query($SQL, , MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($re)<1){
        printf("Sem registros!");
    } else {
        // Laço
         while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($re)){
             printf("%s (%s)\n",$obj->Nome);
         }

          mysqli_free_result($re);
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por me responder, o erro ainda continua você pode conferir pelo seguinte link http://yhsoftware.esy.es/conecta.php

Comment: `$banco` é um objeto PDO ele não vai funcionar com as funções (removidas) mysql_*

Comment: Oque devo fazer para que o PHP funcione seria retirar o $banco ?

Comment: @YuriRuan use a função `mysql_connect()`

Comment: Remova a linha com o mysql_select_db e use mysqli_connect():
`$banco = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.com.br", "u517649386_teste", "senha", "u517649386_teste");`

Comment: @rray "use a função `mysql_connect()`" oxi, tá faltando algo naum?

Comment: consegui resolver obrigado pela resposta de todos ela ajudaram na resolução!

Comment: Essa resposta esta errada.

Answer (score 2):

Existem três formas de fazer o PHP conectar com MySQL, as funções (removidas do php7) [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php), o [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) e o [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php). O código da pergunta misturou o PDO com as funções removidas.

A solução mais simples seria utilizar o MySQLi.

```
$banco = new mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');

if($_GET['acao'] == 'listapizzas'){

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `pizzas` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

     $re = mysqli_query($banco, $sql);

     $num = mysqli_num_row($re);

     if($num > 0){
        while($Linha = mysqli_fetch_object($re)){
           echo "{$Linha->Nome} <br />";
        }
      }else{
         echo 'nenhuma pizza cadastrada';
      }
}
```