# formulario de cadastro de Usuário PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Acabei de implementar esse formulário ([Página do formulário](http://houseofcoin.com/pt/)) no meu site, mas não consegui conectar ao banco de dados para salvar os registros. Usei o `mysql_connect` e ela da esse erro:

> [image: erro]

mudei pra `mysqli` e ainda deu ***erro***.

***Alguém teria como mostra o código que eu posso usar?***

Editando...

usei o código sugerido pelo @Ray BM na página config.php, funcionou mas ele não faz conexão com a tabela, usei o `<?php require("config.php"); ?>` na pagina do formulário.

```
<?php
$servidor = "50.116.87.53"; /*ip da maquina a qual o banco de dados está*/
$usuario = "***"; /*usuario do banco de dados MySql*/
$senha = "***"; /*senha do banco de dados MySql*/
$banco = "***_registo"; /*seleciona o banco a ser usado*/

$conexao = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha);  /*Conecta no bando de dados*/
if (!$conexao){
   die('Não foi possível conectar: '. mysql_error());
   }

mysqli_select_db($conexao,$banco); /*seleciona o banco a ser usado*/

?>
```

como posso salvar os registros se não tem conexão com a tabela?

podem dar uma olhada na página do registro através do link acima. Obrigado !!

Comment: Qual o erro que deu, quando trocou ?

Comment: poderia passar mais detalhes por favor ?

Comment: pergunta atualizada com os erros

Comment: Nunca use prints de texto que você pode copiar, por favor.

Comment: Você disse que mudou para mysqli e ainda dá o erro? Que erro, o mesmo erro? Não teria sentido, se é um novo erro explique qual é. Não basta sair mudando uma coisa outra, siga os exemplos da documentação https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php, as vezes deve-se refazer tudo, não adianta sair copiando colando, aprenda como funciona, se não é o mesmo que você querer dirigir um carro sem saber quando passar a marcha e pegar a estrada sem saber trocar um "estepe". Só vai ter dores de cabeça

Comment: Olá Guilherme, você veio criticar ou tentar ajudar? como pode observar na minha pergunta, há uma edição e logo abaixo está descrito o novo problema que encontrei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conexão direto no mysqli eu faço assim...

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "bancodedados");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falha ao conectar com o mysql: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
```

se precisar mandar a porta de conexao, ficaria assim...

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "bancodedados", 3306);
```

Se quiser trabalhar orientado a objetos utiliza o PDO cara, acredito que vai te ajudar muito mais, e é bem mais fácil trabalhar orientado a objetos com ele...

Abaixo a classe que tenho aqui que faz essa conexão, e um exemplo de outro arquivo utilizando essa conexão...

```
   <?php 
    class Conexao { 
        public $conn; 
        function Conexao() { 
            $string  = "mysql:";
            $string .= "host=localhost ";
            $string .= "port=5432 "; 
            $string .= "dbname=nomedobanco";
            $string .= "user=usuario";
            $string .= "password=senha"; 

            try { 
                $this->conn = new PDO($string);
            }catch(PDOException $e){ 
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }

    }





?>
```

se não quiser utilizar o new PDO com a variavel $string pode usar assim também...

```
new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8mb4', 'username', 'password');
```

se quer uma dica, crie um arquivo "class.conexao.php" com esse código e no "class.suaclasse.php", você utiliza, assim como no exemplo abaixo...

```
<?php 

    require('class.conexao.php');

    class Querys extends Conexao { 


        function validaLogin($login, $senha) { 

            $sql = 
                    "
                        select nome, cpf from validaUsuario('".$login."', '".$senha."');
                    ";

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql); 
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            return $result; 

        }


}
```

essa funcao no caso valida login, ai você pode criar para o que voce precisa...

essa parte

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        return $result;
```

serve para preparar a query que voce vai executar, e depois executar e retorna os resultados associados....

voce utilizaria o retorno desta maneira..

```
<?php   
    require_once('class.querys.php');

    class Login extends Querys { 

        function validarLogin() { 

                $query = new Querys(); 

                $retorno = $query->validaLogin(aqui vem os parametros)); 

                return $retorno;
        }
    }

?>
```

dessa maneira ai você esta trabalhando orientado a objetos.

Comment: fica difícil por eu não entender tanto de mysql, ainda não entendi como eu  vou salvar o Usuário, senha e emal do formulário de cadastro, na tabela do mysql. obrigado

Comment: A conexão está OK agora então?

Comment: Vamos supor que você utilizou a conexão $mysqli que comentei ali acima...

Comment: Para efetuar um cadastro por exemplo, você deve utilizar essa variável que possui a conexão. Ficaria assim $mysqli->query("Insert into tabelausuario (usuário,senha,email) values (suas variáveis com os valores do formulario)")

Comment: Nesse caso você irá inserir os dados na tabelausuario, aí é só trocar o nome da tabela pela sua e colocar os dados...

Comment: a conexão está ok, usei o código que postei

Comment: como assim "(suas variáveis com os valores do formulário)"? os valores não são os usuários que vão colocar?

Comment: no caso tabelausuario seria a tabela dento do banco de dados? 
usuário, senha e email são os campos da tabela ou o imput do form de name"usuário,..."?

Comment: Isso cara, o que eu quis dizer com o "(suas variaveis)" são os valores que voce vai receber do formulario.

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade isto não é um erro e sim uma advertência sobre o uso da função mysql_connect().

Para retirar esta advertência coloque no inicio do código da conexão a seguinte linha:

```
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
```

ou você pode suprimir a mensagem utilizando o @ antes da função.

Ou seja, utilize @mysql_connect(...);

**Porém suprimir erros com @ é sempre uma prática ruim e deve ser evitado.**

A extensão mysql é obsoleta, em seu lugar deve se usar a extinção mysqli, é praticamente igual na hora de usar, sendo que em uma as funções são mysql_* e na outra mysqli_*. Apesar de terem os nomes de funções bem parecido para se tornar fácil migrar de uma para a outra, internamente a mysqli_ é bem melhor.

**Reveja seu código, provavelmente após a alteração a mensagem persistiu devido a utilização de mysql ainda em algum local**. Caso ainda continue com o erro, poste o código.

[Como converter uma ligação de MYSQL para MYSQLI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32820/como-converter-uma-liga%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-mysql-para-mysqli)

Answer (score 2):

eu utilizo o seguinte código para conexão:

```
<?php
$servidor = "0.0.0.0"; /*ip da maquina a qual o banco de dados está*/
$usuario = "usuario"; /*usuario do banco de dados MySql*/
$senha = "senha"; /*senha do banco de dados MySql*/
$banco = "nomedoSchema"; /*seleciona o banco a ser usado*/

$conexao = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha);  /*Conecta no bando de dados*/
if (!$conexao){
   die('Não foi possível conectar: '. mysql_error());
   }

mysqli_select_db($conexao,$banco); /*seleciona o banco a ser usado*/

?>
```

Na inserção utilizo:

```
require("autenticacao/conexao.php");

 $sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (campo) VALUES (valor)"; 
 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql) or die("ocorreu um erro e seu registro não foi inserido");
```

Comment: como posso conectar com a tabela? para salvar os campos.