# Como resolver o erro Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um inventário de TI para cadastro e quero fazer a conexão ao banco de dados, mas tá dando esse erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\cadastrando.php:9 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\cadastrando.php on
>   line 9

Como poderia resolver esse erro?

Segue abaixo o meu código.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" onSubmit="">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Sistema de Inventário</legend><br />

            <label class="borda">Setor: </label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" name="" size="30" required><br />

            <label class="borda">Usuário:</label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="" name="" size="30" required><br />

            <label class="borda">O/S :</label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="email" name="" size="30" required><br /><br />

            <label class="borda">Hd : </label>
            <input  class="form_inp"type="text"  name="" size="30" required><br />                      
            <hr />          
            <label class="borda">Memória:</label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="" name="" size="30" required><br />

            <label class="borda">Processador: </label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id=""  name="" size="30" required><br /><br />
            <hr />
            <label class="borda">Cd/Dvd: </label>
            <select class="form_inp"  name="Dados"> 
                <option value="Sim">Sim</option> 
                <option value="Não">Não</option> 
            </select>

            <br />

            <label class="borda">Placa Mãe: </label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="" name="" size="30" required><br />

            <label class="borda">HostName: </label>
            <input class="form_inp"type="text" id="" name="" size="30" required><br /><br />

            <label class="borda">Monitor/Patrimônio/Marca/Modelo: </label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="" name="" size="30" required><br />

            <label class="borda">Nobreak/Patrimônio/Marca/: </label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="" name="" size="30" required><br />

            <label class="borda">Placa de Rede : </label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="" name="" size="30" required><br />

            <label class="borda">Placa de Vídeo: </label>
            <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="" name="" size="30" required><br />

            <hr />
            <input type="submit" style="float: right;" value="Cadastrar" >
            <input type="reset" style="float: right;" value="Limpar">

        </fieldset>
```

php/bancodedados:

```
  <html>
   <head><title>Cadastrando...</title></head>
    <body>
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user ="roor";
$pass = "";
$banco = "cadastro";
$link = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "database"); 
mysqli_select_db($banco) or die (mysqli_error());
?>
<?php
$setor=$_POST['setor'];
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$hd=$_POST['hd'];
$memoria=$_POST['memoria'];
$propressador=$_POST['processador'];
$cd=$_POST['cd'];
$placam=$_POST['placam'];
$host=$_POST['host'];
$monitor=$_POST['monitor'];
$nobreak=$_POST['nobreak'];
$placar=$_POST['placar'];
$placav=$_POST['placav'];
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO setor(setor,usuario,hd,memoria,processador,cd,placam,host,monitor,nobreak,placar,plavav) VALUES('$setor,$usuario,$hd,$memoria,$processador,$cd,$placam,$host,$monitor,$nobreak,$placar,$placav'))");
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: estou usando o php 7

Comment: No PHP7 essas funções não existem mais.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql da uma lida se puder.

Comment: Se for atulizar um código com o MySQLi pode olhar [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32822/91)

Comment: @rray fiz uma atualização e deu um erro diferente e tentei outras formas e deu o mesmo erro .

Comment: Como já disse o @rray, esta função foi descontinuada (é o 1o parágrafo da resposta aceita na original, indicada no quadro amarelo).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A função `mysql_connect()` foi descontinuado.

Agora se usa `mysqli_connect()`.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "database");
```

Isso também vale para os outros comandos que comecem com `mysql_`. Devem ser `mysqli_`.

Portanto:

```
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: Fiz uma atualização mais apareceu esse erro e fiz de outras formas e nada ;Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: O nome solicitado �

Comment: Isso aconteceu porquê provavelmente os dados de conexão estão errados.