# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, html, mysql

pessoal efetuei a criação de um form html acompanhando de um arquivo de conexão e recebimento de dados deste form (em php), porem, ao clicar no input que chama a action recebe, me aparece o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

os codigos estão assim:

**html:**

```
<label>Nome</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="nome" /><br />
<label>Idade</label><br />
    <input type="number" name="idade" /><br />
<label>Telefone</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="telefone" /><br />
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" />
</p>
```

**conexao.php**

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); $db = 
mysql_select_db("videoaula", $con);

if(!$con) {     die("Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados; " . mysql_error()); }

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf-8'"); mysql_query('SET character_set_connecton=utf-8'); mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf-8'); mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf-8');
```

**recebe.php:**

```
require_once("connection/conexao.php");


$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$idade = $_POST["idade"];
$telefone = $_POST["telefone"];


$sql = "INSERT INTO `clientes` (`nome`, `idade`, `telefone`) VALUES ('$nome', '$idade', '$telefone')";

if(!$sql) {
    echo("Houve um erro na inserção do banco de dados");
        } else 
    {
        echo("Dados inseridos com sucesso");
    }
```

obrigado desde ja

Comment: Se estiver usando PHP 7, as funções `mysql_*` foram removidas. Utilize as funções `mysqli_*` no lugar.

Comment: possivel duplicata https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173037/como-resolver-o-erro-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect e aqui  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql

Comment: A função mysql_connect() foi descontinuado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A função `mysql_connect()` ficou obsoleta no PHP 5.5.0 e as funções `mysql_ *` foram removidas no PHP7!**

O PHP oferece as API mysqli e PDO para se conectar a um servidor MySQL.

Com [MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)  a conexão pode ser feita do seguinte modo:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "USUARIO";
$password = "SENHA";
$dbname = "videoaula";

$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$con) {
    die("Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados" . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

E tem que mudar também:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `clientes` (`nome`, `idade`, `telefone`) VALUES ('$nome', '$idade', '$telefone')";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf-8'"); 
mysqli_query('SET character_set_connecton=utf-8'); 
mysqli_query('SET character_set_client=utf-8'); 
mysqli_query('SET character_set_results=utf-8');
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, preferi refazer e deu tudo certo deste modo. Valeu!