# Como corrigir o erro HTTP 500?

Tags: php

Estou tentando rodar o código abaixo mas estou recebendo a mensagem `HTTP ERROR 500`, como posso corrigir?

```
<?php

//chama o arquivo de conexão com o banco
include("connect_db.php");

//consulta mysqli
$query = mysql_query("SELECT numero, orig, dest, eqpt, rota FROM voos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());

//aqui ele gera looping e cria um array com os campos da consulta
$array = mysql_fetch_array($query)
foreach($array as $indice => $item)
{
    if(isset($array[$indice + 1])){
        echo $array[$indice]['numero'];
        echo $array[$indice]['orig'];
        echo $array[$indice]['dest'];
        echo $array[$indice]['eqpt'];
        echo $array[$indice]['rota'];
        echo "<br>";
        //Se for o item 2 primeiro inverta a parte de baixo com a de cima
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['numero'];
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['orig'];
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['dest'];
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['eqpt'];
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['rota'];
    }
?>
<br />
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Falta um `;` no final de:

```
$array = mysql_fetch_array($query)
```

Mude para:

```
$array = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Testei o resto e parece normal.

**Observação:**

As funções como `mysql_query`, `mysql_connect` e outras que começam com o **prefixo** `mysql_` foram descontinuadas no PHP5.3 e removidas no PHP7, ou seja se teu servidor for PHP7 elas não vão funcionar, as APIs modernas são o mysqli e o PDO, migre o quanto antes possivel para essas novas APIs, se não teu script pode vir a falhar no futuro (ou talvez já esteja falho devido a isto).

Recomendo que leia: [Como converter uma ligação de MYSQL para MYSQLI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32820/como-converter-uma-liga%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-mysql-para-mysqli/32822#32822)

### Um exemplo simples de uso do MySqli:

Um exemplo "procedural" de uso do mysqli:

```
<?php
//$link é a variavel da "conexão"
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* Verifica erros de conexão */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * ....') or die(mysqli_error($link));


/* array associativa */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    ....
}

/* libera a memoria */
mysqli_free_result($result);

/* fecha a conexão */
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Fiz  e edição e agradeço pela ajuda, mas continuou aparecendo mesma mensagem em meu site > http://latamvirtual.net/core/gera_escala.php

Comment: @JoaquimAlberico Veja a edição da resposta.

Comment: Guiherme agradeço sua ajuda, fiz as alterações que eu consigo "entender" até porque não sou programador mas o erro persiste.

Comment: @JoaquimAlberico deve ser dentro do connect_db.php

Comment: Mas mesmo eu chamando o $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world"); de dentro do arquivo o erro persiste, pode ser alguma configuração de onde eu hospedo o site ?

Comment: @JoaquimAlberico vc deve ter feito algo errado quando mudou pra mysqli, vc seguiu o exemplo que postei? Entenda que mysqli_ é totalmente diferente de mysql_, as funções se parecem, mas na verdade não são iguais, então não basta trocar mysql_ por mysqli_, recomendo que refaça os códigos seguindo a risca o exemplo, e troque o my_user, my_password e world pelo seu login, senha e nome do banco que vocÊ usa no seu banco de dados mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Todas as alterações pelo o que eu entendi foram feitas. Desculpas o trabalho isso é apenas um hobby e um site de hobby nada profissional, estou tentando aprender ainda, obrigado mesmo pela ajuda !

```
<?php

//chama o arquivo de conexão com o banco
//$link é a variavel da "conexão"
$link = mysqli_connect("meuhost.com.br", "usuario", "senha", "db");

//consulta mysqli
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT numero, orig, dest, eqpt, rota FROM voos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5') or die(mysqli_error($link));

//aqui ele gera looping e cria um array com os campos da consulta
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
foreach($array as $indice => $item)
{
    if(isset($array[$indice + 1])){
        echo $array[$indice]['numero'];
        echo $array[$indice]['orig'];
        echo $array[$indice]['dest'];
        echo $array[$indice]['eqpt'];
        echo $array[$indice]['rota'];
        echo "<br>";
        //Se for o item 2 primeiro inverta a parte de baixo com a de cima
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['numero'];
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['orig'];
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['dest'];
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['eqpt'];
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['rota'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Teu código está totalmente diferente do que eu te ensinei a usar. Cadê o `mysqli_connect_errno`? Refaça seguindo exatamente o que eu fiz: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/241529/3635

Comment: Eu gerei outro codigo aqui, e o erro persiste, eu hospedo o site na hostinger e estou vendo outras pessos com esse mesmo erro :(

Comment: Joaquim gerou outro código, mas não informou como refez ele, sem ver o código não posso ver aonde você falhou, entende?