# Como mudar Mysql para Mysqli

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados

Bom, Metade do meu projeto esta usando mysql mais adicionei uma nova função que usa mysqli o que esta gerando alguns conflitos no banco de dados. Ou ele salva o que esta em mysql ou o que esta em mysqli. Tentei mudar pra mysqli mais não consegui fazer funcionar.

Quando uso esse script mysql só não funciona os mysqli

```js
<?php

error_reporting(0);
ini_set(“display_errors”, 0 );

$conectar = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Erro na conexão");
mysql_select_db("tcc")or die ("Base não encontrada");
?>
```

Já esse só funciona o mysqli e não os mysql

```js
<?php
 $servidor = "localhost";
 $usuario = "root";
 $senha = "";
 $dbname = "usuarios";
 
 //Criar a conexao
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
?>
```

Queria saber como eu mudo o mysqli pro mysql já tentei remover os **i** do mysqli mais não da certo.

---

Mudei minha conexão para mysqli_ e não consigo logar com usuário possivelmente porque não esta conectando ao banco devido os códigos serem em mysql_

O código de login

```js
<?php
session_start();
$usuariot = $_POST['usuario'];
$senhat = $_POST['senha'];
include_once("conexao.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login='$usuariot' AND senha='$senhat' LIMIT 1");
$resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
//echo "Usuario: ".$resultado['nome'];
if(empty($resultado)){
 //Mensagem de Erro
 $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha Inválido";
 
 //Manda o usuario para a tela de login
 header("Location: index.php");
}else{
 //Define os valores atribuidos na sessao do usuario
 $_SESSION['usuarioId']    = $resultado['id'];
 $_SESSION['usuarioNome']   = $resultado['nome'];
 $_SESSION['usuarioNivelAcesso'] = $resultado['nivel_acesso_id'];
 $_SESSION['usuarioLogin']   = $resultado['login'];
 $_SESSION['usuarioSenha']   = $resultado['senha'];
 
 if($_SESSION['usuarioNivelAcesso'] == 1){
  header("Location: administrativo.php");
 }else{
  header("Location: usuario.php");
 }
}
?>
```

Tentei mudar os **mysql_query** e o **mysql_fetch_assoc** acrescentando os **i**  mais não foi suficiente não consigo logar

Comment: pq vc vai usar funções obsoletas?

Comment: 99% do meu projeto esta em mysql não queria ter o trabalho de mudar tudo

Comment: Depende como está o código mas não da muito trabalho. A principal diferença é que nas funções `mysqli_` o primeiro argumento quase sempre é a conexão já no `mysql_` a conexão é o segundo argumento e não é obrigatório.

Comment: [Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32822/91) Tem um exemplo de como migrar do mysql_ para o mysqli_.

Comment: Pode me auxiliar nesta parte pois essa é semelhante as outras assim posso mudar tudo para mysqli_

Comment: Reforçando o que o @rray disse, porquê usar funções que já não existem na versão 7 do php ? Isso não resolve o problema, apenas o adia. Mais tarde provavelmente vai voltar ao mesmo problema e vai ser forçado a trocar mesmo. Faça correto e troque já tudo para `mysqli`