# Como criar os mesmos códigos para rodar em php7?

Tags: php, mysqli

Bom gente sou um pouco atrasado nas coisas e, até agora não consegui aprender o php7 novamente.

Bom esses arquivos(3) ai que estou mostrando a vocês é a maneira como eu faço para mostrar registro do banco de dados de uma forma show. Gostaria de saber se existe alum meio de criar uma versão atualizada desses códigos.

Ou se existe algo mais atual e fácil de estar implementando em meus projetos.

```
conection.php

<?php


  class xDatabase{


    var $DB_HOSTNAME        = "localhost";
    var $DB_USERNAME        = "user";
    var $DB_PASSWORD        = "";
    var $DB_DATABASE        = "Xbanco";





    var $DB_CONNECTION      = false;

    var $DB_RESULT          = false;
    var $DB_RESULT_ROWS     = 0;   
    var $DB_AFFECTED_ROWS   = 0;
    var $DB_PREV_INSERT_ID  = 0;    

    function xDatabase() {
      $this->DB_CONNECTION = @mysql_connect($this->DB_HOSTNAME, $this->DB_USERNAME, $this->DB_PASSWORD);
      if (!$this->DB_CONNECTION);
      if (!@mysql_select_db($this->DB_DATABASE));
    }

    function query($query) {
      if (!$this->DB_CONNECTION) 
        return false;
      if (!$this->DB_RESULT = @mysql_query($query, $this->DB_CONNECTION))
        return false;
        switch(strtoupper(substr($query, 0, 6))){
        case "SELECT" : $this->DB_RESULT_ROWS = @mysql_num_rows($this->DB_RESULT);                       
                        while ($db_result = mysql_fetch_array($this->DB_RESULT, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                        {
                            $db_data[] = $db_result;
                        }                       
                       if (is_array($db_data))
                       {
                         return $db_data;
                       }
                       else
                          return false;


                        break;

        case "INSERT" : $this->DB_AFFECTED_ROWS = @mysql_affected_rows($this->DB_RESULT);
                        $this->DB_PREV_INSERT_ID = @mysql_insert_id();
                        break;

        case "DELETE" : $this->DB_AFFECTED_ROWS = @mysql_affected_rows($this->DB_RESULT);
                        break;

        case "UPDATE" : $this->DB_AFFECTED_ROWS = @mysql_affected_rows($this->DB_RESULT);
                        break;
      }        

      return true;
    }

    function querySingle($query)
    {
      if (!$db_result = $this->query($query))
        return false;

      return $db_result[0];
    }       

    function clean()
    {
      if ((!$this->DB_CONNECTION) || (!$this->DB_RESULT))
        return false;

      if (!(@mysql_free_result($this->DB_RESULT)))
        return false;

      $this->DB_RESULT         = false;
      $this->DB_RESULT_ROWS    = 0;
      $this->DB_AFFECTED_ROWS  = 0;
      $this->DB_PREV_INSERT_ID = 0;

      return true;
    }

    function close()
    {
      if (!$this->DB_CONNECTION)
        return false;

      if (@mysql_close($this->DB_CONNECTION))
      {
        $this->DB_RESULT         = false;
        $this->DB_CONNECTION     = false;
        $this->DB_RESULT_ROWS    = 0;
        $this->DB_PREV_INSERT_ID = 0;

        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }   
  }

?>


class.exibir.php


<?php
    class Exibir
    {
        var $DB_RESULT_ROWS = 0;


        ########## Empresa ############

        function Sobre(){
            $db = new xDataBase();
            $strSql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_sobre` WHERE id = 1";
            $result = $db->query($strSql);
            $this->DB_RESULT_ROWS = $db->DB_RESULT_ROWS;
            $db->close();
            if($this->DB_RESULT_ROWS != 0){
                return($result);
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
?>


sobre.php

<?php  $B = $Exibir->Sobre(); if(is_array($B)){  foreach($B as $b) { ?>

<?php echo utf($b['Texto']); ?>

<?php  } } // Fecha Foreach
 else{ echo "Falha ao exibir resultados do banco de dados!!!";} // Fecha Else
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Utilize PDO.

> A utilização do PDO fornece uma camada de abstração em relação a conexão com o banco de dados visto que o PDO efetua a conexão com diversos bancos de dados da mesma maneira, modificando apenas a sua string de conexão.

Dê uma olhada na documentação do PHP7 e em técnicas de programação orientada à objetos.

Eu, particularmente, faço a conexão com o banco desta forma:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_CHAR', 'utf8');

class Database{

    // specify your own database credentials

    private static $conn;

    // get the database connection
    public static function getConnection(){

        if(static::$conn == null){
                try{
                    $opt  = array(
                        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => FALSE,
                    );
                    $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
                    static::$conn = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
                }catch(PDOException $exception){
                    die("Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage());
                }
        }
        return static::$conn;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Bom acredito que o meu problema não era quanto a conexão em pdo mas, sim quanto a um arquivo de classe com funções que conectem a uma tabela diferente!

Answer (score -1):

Bom o que gostaria de tentar fazer era essas funções que conecta as suas tabelas estipuladas na query. Vejo que as mesmas param de funcionar no PHP 7.1.

class.exibir.php

```
<?php
    class Exibir
    {
        var $DB_RESULT_ROWS = 0;


        ########## Empresa ############

        function Sobre(){
            $db = new xDataBase();
            $strSql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_sobre` WHERE id = 1";
            $result = $db->query($strSql);
            $this->DB_RESULT_ROWS = $db->DB_RESULT_ROWS;
            $db->close();
            if($this->DB_RESULT_ROWS != 0){
                return($result);
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        function Contato(){
            $db = new xDataBase();
            $strSql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_contato` WHERE id = 1";
            $result = $db->query($strSql);
            $this->DB_RESULT_ROWS = $db->DB_RESULT_ROWS;
            $db->close();
            if($this->DB_RESULT_ROWS != 0){
                return($result);
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Segundo a [documentação da extensão `mysql` do PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), estes métodos foram descontinuados na versão 5.5 do PHP e removidos no PHP 7.

A maneira menos intrusiva de alteração do teu código acho seria usando a extensão [`mysqli`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) com a interface procedural, pois é mais próximo do teu código atual. Como dito na [documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php)

> Users migrating from the old mysql extension may prefer the procedural interface. The procedural interface is similar to that of the old mysql extension. In many cases, the function names differ only by prefix. Some mysqli functions take a connection handle as their first argument, whereas matching functions in the old mysql interface take it as an optional last argument.

Tradução livre:

> Usuários que estão migrando da versão antiga da extensão mysql podem preferir a interface procedural. A interface procedural é similar à interface da extensão antiga. Em muitos casos, os nomes das funções se diferenciam apenas pelo prefixo. Algumas funções `mysqli` recebem um *handle* de conexão como primeiro argumento, onde a mesma função na extensão antiga, recebe o *handle* como último argumento, sendo este opcional.

Ou seja, a refatoração se resumiriam mais a trocar `mysql_*` por `mysqli_*` e cuidar os casos onde ocorrem as exceções citadas acima. [Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32822/6333), conforme marcado pelos moderadores, contém maiores informações de como fazer esta refatoração.

Comment: Alguma dica do que está errado na resposta, ou é só -1 sem mais nem menos?

Comment: Não entendi! A resposta do fernandosavio foi a melhor por que explica onde tem o erro e o cara ganhou um -1 :(

Comment: Tirando a parte que sugere o PDO no ultimo parágrafo, o resto tá bom, não vejo motivo pra -1 nessa aqui. Talvez um exemplo de código ajudasse um pouco.

Comment: Não foi exatamente uma sugestão para usar PDO, mas sim para usar PDO, mysqli ou ORM. Não foi em ordem de importância. De qualquer maneira vou editar e resposta porque essa parte não acrescenta muito à resposta mesmo.